# The target ... overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have incorporate `SpatialIite` into a Xcode project which uses a header file from `Proj.4`, just one header. Both are Xcode projects and have static targets.

I'm trying to migrate from git submodule to Cocoapods. Since static targets seems to be difficult to use with Cocoapods, I just want to have the project built in the usual way. I made podspec for `Proj.4`. After writing podfile for `SpatialLite` I got the warnings:

```
[!] The target `SpatialiteIOS [Debug]` overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The target `SpatialiteIOS [Debug]` overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The target `SpatialiteIOS [Debug - Release]` overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The target `SpatialiteIOS [Debug - Release]` overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I read [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1125) but I'm pretty clueless to what the warnings mean and what can I do to fix it.

Additionally problem, when I open the workspace as well as opening SpatiaLite project alone, both are targeted to Mac OSX 64, when it is suppose to be an iOS project. My podfile does say "platform :ios".

Comment: 2020 - for anyone struggling with this annoying problem. It is really only caused by (Surprise! :) ) facebook.  As explained HERE, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui  **"If you prefer, you can add only the Auth component and the providers you want to use..."** once you eliminate the facebook option, there's no problem. :/

Answer (score 581, accepted):

This definitely works most of the time:

Go to your target Build Settings -> Other linker flags -> double click . Add `$(inherited)` to a new line.

If you have problem with "...target overrides the GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS build setting defined in..." then you must add $(inherited) to your target Build Settings -> Preprocessor Macros

Comment: Does anyone know where actually the settings inherited from?

Comment: your projects has certain flags , another target such as POD dependencies has other flags. You might be using POD.xcworkspace to run . In that case the flags which your main project holds is not neglected , its inherited and used too.

Comment: I would extend this answer. If you have problem with "... target overrides the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` build setting defined in ..." then you must add $(inherited) to your target Build Settings -> Preprocessor Macros

Comment: i suspect that "... target overrides the INSERT_YOUR_MISSING_DEFINITION..." then you must add $(inherited) to it. oddly though, my xcode was showing $(inherited) a bit faint as by default. i edited and simply retyped the same thing. error disappeared..

Comment: try reinstalling pod after added $(inherited)

Comment: You might have  4 settings in Other Linker flags for the project that is trying to use the Pods.  These must all include $(inhereited).  For me, there is Debug, and under Debug is Any Architecture | Any SDK.  Same for Release.  The Debug and Release for me were blank, but the subkeys had the $(inhereted) value.  The easiest way to check is to make sure the top level does not say <Multiple Values>

Comment: @joe Still not working for me. I tried all these suggestions, but when I rerun pod install, the errors persist. I made the changes to both other linker flags and to preprocessor macros. In both cases, nothing shows until you double click on each of the lines in other linker flags and preprocessor macros. Then you can see that $(inherited) has been added. I tried deleting and readding. I tried closing and reopening xcode. Nothing fixes the error messages when I type in pod install.

Comment: @msmq It's been a long time now, but do you remember the workaround that you tried and got it working? `$(inherited)` is already there at the top line but it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: @msmq Can you remove that line and add it again, then try pod install. Hope it works.

Answer (score 80):

There is a conflict between your build settings and the default build settings that Cocoapods wants. To see the Cocoapods build settings, view the .xcconfig file(s) in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-${PROJECTNAME}/ in your project. For me this file contains:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Commando"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

If you are happy with the Cocoapods settings, then go to Build Settings for your project, find the appropriate setting and hit the Delete key. This will use the setting from Cocoapods.

On the other hand, if you have a custom setting that you need to use, then add $(inherited) to that setting.

Comment: I had this problem as well, I was able to remove the -ObjC and that fixed this problem. However, when I attempted to build the project, I get an error suggesting that the target specific pod library can not be found: "ld: library not found for -lPods-MyProject". Did you see something similar?

Comment: I'm run into this again. I'm not sure $(inherited) means. Where do I add it?

Comment: @RodericCampbell I have found that removing -ObjC from the project works fine for me and I don't see your error.

Comment: Hmm, but I need the -ObjC flag for it at runtime since I got categories.

Comment: One solution is to create an xcconfig for your own projects that overrides the Pod version.

Comment: how do you find the 'appropriate setting' for deletion? It just says 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' without regard to what those might be. I tried deleting 'Other Linker Flags' from the build settings but it doesn't seem possible. If you mean to clear the entire 'Other Linker Flags' section out then that didn't work for me either.

Comment: OTHER_LDFLAGS = Other Linked Flags, HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = Header Search Paths, GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = Preprocessor Macros. @kraftydevil, what setting are you trying to delete?

Answer (score 33):

I've seen these 3 errors for pod command in terminal

```
pod install
```

> [!] The MY_APP [Debug/Release] target overrides the
>   HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS ...
>   [!] The MY_APP [Debug/Release] target
>   overrides the OTHER_LDFLAGS ...
>   [!] The MY_APP [Debug/Release] target
>   overrides the GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS ...

All these 3 errors would be gone by adding *$(inherited)* to

1. Header Search Paths
2. Other Linker Flags
3. Preprocessor Macros

in *Project -> Target -> Build Settings*

And now the command would run without giving any errors

```
pod install
```

Comment: The above worked for me, when simply changing the flag for `Other Linker Flags` wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 23):

Just had a similar issue when I ran `pod install`, I saw the following warnings/errors (related to `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY`):

#### The Error/Warning from Cocoapods

```
[!] The `Project [Debug]` target overrides the `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Project [Release]` target overrides the `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

#### The Fix

1. Select your `Project` so you can see the `Build Settings`.
2. Select your `Target` (`AppName` under `Targets`)
3. Find `C++ Standard Library` (It will probably be in **BOLD** - This means it's overridden).
4. Select the Line (So it's highlighted Blue), and press <kbd>⌘ + DELETE</kbd> (Command + Backspace)

The line should not be bolded anymore and if you run `pod install` the warnings/errors should have disappeared.

---

#### Visual Aid

[image: CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY Error/Warning with Cocoapods]

Answer (score 21):

In your project, find `Target -> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags`, select `Other Linker Flags`, press `delete`(Mac Keyboard)/`Backspace`(Normal keyboard) to recover the setting. It works for me.

Example:

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Answer (score 13):

If Xcode complains while linking, e.g. Library not found for -lPods, it doesn't detect the implicit dependencies:

Go to Product > Edit Scheme
Click on Build
Add the Pods static library
Clean and build again

Answer (score 13):

For me the problem was with my targets tests. I already had the `$(inherited)` flag in my main app target.

I added it to MyAppTests Other Linker flags. After that when I ran `pod install` the warning message was gone. 
[image]

Answer (score 6):

The first line of link below saved my day:

> To add values to options from your project’s build settings, prepend the value list with $(inherited).

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-a-project-that-uses-CocoaPods#faq

Also, do not forget to insert this line at the beginning of your pod file:

```
platform :iOS, '5.0'
```

Answer (score 6):

I added $(inherited) but my project was still not compiling. For me problem was flag "Build for active Architecture only", I had to set it to YES.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode Screenshot

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Ankish Jain had the answer that worked for me. Here is a screenshot of what to do, as it took me a little bit to find out what exactly to do.

In my case i needed to add $(inherited) to my 'Other Linker Flags' because that is what showed up as Overriding in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

do not forget to insert (or unCommanet) this line at the beginning of your pod file:

```
platform :iOS, '9.0'
```

that saves my day

Comment: Wrong. It has to be `platform: ios, '9.0'` and it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I added the $(inherited) flag to the file in question (in this case it was LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS) it led to another error `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContextInMetadataState`

Changing the following worked and I was able to build:

```
>LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
   "\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"",
-  "\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"", <--- Change this...
+  "\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.2/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"", <--- to this
   "\"$(inherited)\"",
> );
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens to me every time I add a pod to the podfile.

I constantly try and find the problem but I just go round in circles again and again!

The error messages range, however the way to fix it is the same every time!

Comment out(#) ALL of the pods in the podfile and run pod install in terminal.

Then...

Uncomment out all of the pods in the podfile and run pod install again.

This has worked for me every single time!