# Unable to find a specification for `Mapbox` installing with CocoaPods for iOS 7

Tags: installation, cocoapods, mapbox

I am building an app targeted to iOS 7 and I want to use Mapbox.  I added

pod 'Mapbox'

to my Podfile, but 'pod install' responds with:

[!] Unable to find a specification for `Mapbox`.

I cannot change back to platform :ios, '5.0' because I have other libraries that require the later version.  Is there a CocoaPod for MapBox that works with iOS 7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

CocoaPods is case sensitive. You need to specify `MapBox`

Comment: Thanks.  The instructions at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/ should be changed, because it says pod 'Mapbox' there.  However, after the pod installed successfully, I am getting link errors: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_pj_free", referenced from:
      -[RMProjection dealloc] in libPods.a(RMProjection.o)
  "_pj_fwd", referenced from:
      -[RMProjection coordinateToProjectedPoint:] in libPods.a(RMProjection.o)
  "_pj_init_plus", referenced from:
      -[RMProjection initWithString:inBounds:] in libPods.a(RMProjection.o)
...

Comment: You may want to checkout out this discussion. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/issues/230 Looks like the newer versions should have fixed that.

Comment: Also maybe related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64

Answer (score 0):

The old closed issue at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/issues/230 isn't the problem here.

This is: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/issues/377

Which details the fix for now:

```
pod 'Mapbox', :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk', :tag => '1.1.0'
```