# Error when trying to run app app on iPad Air, Apple Mach-O Linker Warning and Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, ios7

I have an app that I'm testing. I have been using on the previous version iPad Mini but am borrowing a current iPad Air. I am able to add to developer profile but get this error when trying to build onto iPad Air. It looks like an error in two pods that I'm using AMSlideoutController and AFNetworking. Here's my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
pod 'AMSlideOutController'
```

I have the feeling that this is some really simple Product config for 64 bit am not really sure. How can I resolve this?

Here's the error that I'm getting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

add -ObjC in the "other linker flags" section of your build settings

Then make sure your Build Phases have all the "Link Binary With Library" references that you need. Seems you're missing at least one AFNetworking related library, or have linked to a partial library that doesn't contain the extra classes the linker can't find.

Comment: thx Ryan, I have the feeling that it is similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64 but I am unfortunately getting an error on pod install. So maybe an issue with 64bit AFNetworking