# TestFlight shows symbol not found error in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am getting the following  error while running my app on a device from Xcode **5.1**. while it Build succesfully in **Xcode 5.0.2**

```
/Users/XX/TestFlightSDK/libTestFlight.a (4 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TestFlight", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in XXDataTypes.o
      objc-class-ref in XXAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have added arm64 as valid architecture and libTestFlight.a in LinkBinaryWithLibrary, and note that this **error shows only in Xcode 5.1** any suggestions or help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the TestFlight library you are using is not built for `arm64` architecture. Check on TestFlight website for latest version which contains `arm64`.

You can cross check by running the `lipo` command on the `.a` file as,

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libTestFlight.a
```

This should list out the architectures contained in the FAT file. Check for existence of `arm64` or something like `(cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0))`. If it is not present assume that lib is not built for `arm64`.

Hope that helps!

**NOTE** : TestFlight 3.0.0 is the latest version which supports arm64 ARCH, But this SDK can only be dowloaded if there is an already uploaded build. Check This

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1452760

Comment: Yes,  armv7 armv7s armv6 i386 are the only archs supported by testflight lib I am using. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **Xcode 5.02** stable version (As you mention in your question that these error resolve by using **Xcode 5.02**, the reason behind is that **Xcode 5.01** is beta version and it not stable).
Same problems I was facing too before installing **Xcode 5.02**.

Hopefully this info will helps you.

Comment: I am using Xcode 5.1 which is a stable release with iOS 7.1. I think this issue related to the 64bit architecture

Comment: I think the TestFlight you are using, does not support arm64.Kindly check the following link it will hopefully helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64