# Cocoapods ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, cocoapods

After updating my pods and xcode, I've come across problems in the last phase of the build process (linking). I've tried switching up the architectures as well as setting the build active architecture to on and off, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SRWebSocket", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in BLYClient.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in BLYClient.o
"_kReachabilityChangedNotification", referenced from:
-[BLYClient initWithAppKey:delegate:hostName:] in BLYClient.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequestConnection", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCAccountRegistrationViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCAccountRegistrationViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_JASidePanelController", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS_$_LCMainRevealController in LCMainRevealController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SEEPhoneNumberFormatter", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCPhoneFormatter.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKInnerShadowLayer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCInnerShadowView.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPClient", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS_$_LCHTTPClient in LCHTTPClient.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_JASidePanelController", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$_LCMainRevealController in LCMainRevealController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BITHockeyManager", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCAppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCHTTPClient.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Lockbox", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCKey.o
objc-class-ref in LCSettings.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCApi+Internal.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCAppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestOperation", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCHTTPClient.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPClient", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$_LCHTTPClient in LCHTTPClient.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RHDisplayLinkStepper", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCLockSwipeView.o
objc-class-ref in LCLockUpdatingProgressView.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MagicalRecord", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LCAppDelegate.o
objc-class-ref in LCApi+Locks.o
objc-class-ref in LCApi+Keys.o
objc-class-ref in LCBTLockScanner.o
objc-class-ref in LCBTLockForegroundScanner.o
objc-class-ref in LCBTLock.o
objc-class-ref in LCRootViewController.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64 What did you set in Build Settings > Architectures?

Comment: This is what it looks like: http://imgur.com/u5066Rd

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. The "Other Linker Flags" was overriding the flags from CocoaPods. In fact I got a warning about it-

```
[!] The `sftest [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-sftest/Pods-sftest.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Changing "Other Linker Flags" to $(inherited) did indeed solve the problem.