# AFNetworking won't compile

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, cocoapods

I'm totally stuck trying to run a project on the simulator using AFNetworking. I've used this dependency before on other projects, so I don't understand what is going wrong here. First, the error when I try to run the project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SharedNetworkObject in SharedNetworkObject.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SharedNetworkObject.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SharedNetworkObject in SharedNetworkObject.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm sure that this is part of the problem, but I don't know how to resolve it:

[image]

This is the offending .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
#import "SharedSessionKey.h"

@interface SharedNetworkObject : AFHTTPSessionManager

+ (SharedNetworkObject *) sharedNetworkObject;   // class method to return the singleton object

@end
```

It may be of interest to note that when I start typing the import line for AFNetworking, the line fills in after a few characters, so I know that there is some awareness of the presence of the AFNetworking dependency.

I installed the dependency using CocoaPods. Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'WeRun' do
pod "AFNetworking", "2.5.2"
end

target 'WeRunTests' do

end
```

And, of course I am working in `.xcworkspace` (not `.xcodeproj`).

One more thing, my xcconfig file looks like this, which matches with other successful AFNetworking builds:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AFNetworking"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AFNetworking"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC -l"Pods-MyApp-AFNetworking" -framework "CoreGraphics" -framework "MobileCoreServices" -framework "Security" -framework "SystemConfiguration"
OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS = $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

I don't know what else to look for. I've completely removed the pod and reinstalled, only to find the exact same error. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2324

Comment: Set build active architecture only to yes

Comment: @Jassi - didn't work.

Comment: Please check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64?rq=1) There are various options being tried by other users. It might help you.

Comment: @KlevisonMatias - thanks. I 've tried these, but they only make the problem worse.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I spent a couple of hours fighting with this exact same issue, going through all the Google hits I could find. Building for the device was working, but building for the simulator was not.

Here are the steps that finally solved the issue for me:

1. Clear the XCode caches:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
   ```
2. Clear the CocoaPods caches and reinstall the dependencies:

   ```
   rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
   rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
   pod update
   ```
3. Finally go to the "Pods" project and set the `Build Active Architectures Only` to `No` also for the "Debug" configuration.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: it works, thanks! this should be the correct answer.

Comment: Finally a working solution!! Thank you very much (Y) :D

Comment: Thank you! This saved my a** :D

Comment: You're a god amongst men. OUT OF NOWHERE in the middle of a programming session my project started throwing these errors and this fixed it. <3

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to add the $(inherited) flag into the "Build settings".

- Tap on the blue project icon
- Select "Build settings" tab
- Under "Linking" you'll find a setting called "Other Linker Flags"
- add $(inherited) into the textfield

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, when I had `-lc++` already set on `Other linker flags` for cpp library usage purpose.
I added these two flags `-ObjC -l"AFNetworking"` on `Other linker flags`, which worked and compiled successfully. These are the two flags `-ObjC` and `-l"AFNetworking"`. You scan add simultaneously `-ObjC -l"AFNetworking"`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not give version after AFNetworking in pod file. And try again. Make sure you remove the comma also.

Comment: I don't have version numbers in my Podfile. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved this, but I'm not sure why it worked. I was experimenting with the Other Linker Flags in the Build Settings. I deleted the flag that was put there by the CocoaPods installation (presumably) and replaced it by copying the flag from the `.xcconfig` file. Specifically, I added this text: `-l"Pods-WeRun-AFNetworking"` as the second flag right after `-ObjC`. It looks to me to be exactly what I had just deleted, so I really hesitate to suggest this as an 'answer', but it works now, so something must have changed.

If anyone can shed any light on this or tell me that I am fooling myself, please let me know. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me too. and what I fixed it just one step:

Kill the Xcode, and right click the Xcode to show info, open it using Rosetta, then open the project to build. It works!!!
By the way, I am using M1-chip Mac Mini.
Before that, I tried everything I got from google, like: clean the cache, check the other linked flag, etc. they won't work for me.

I hope this can help you guys!

Answer (score -2):

A simple method. Download the repository file. Drag and drop the contents of the AFnetworking folder (You can create groups if necessary) then use the library. (Use #import "AFnetworking.h" )