# Xcode 8: Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 for pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors, xcode8

After updating to Xcode 8, the app won't run on devices, only on the simulator. The errors are thrown for all pods added to the project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkReachabilityManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FeedViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TSMessage", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_TSMessage_$_Override in NotificationMessenger.o
      objc-class-ref in NotificationMessenger.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HTTPSessionTask.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HTTPSessionTask.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SWTableViewCell", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MessagesCell in MessagesCell.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PaymentMethodCell in PaymentMethodCell.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SwipeTitleCell in SwipeTitleCell.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequestConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SWTableViewCell", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MessagesCell in MessagesCell.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PaymentMethodCell in PaymentMethodCell.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SwipeTitleCell in SwipeTitleCell.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFURLSessionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HTTPSessionTask.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Branch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyImpactViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in UINavigationController+Activity.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookManager.o
      objc-class-ref in ExternalFacebookCommand.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

For each of the files, this warning is also thrown:

```
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)
```

Active architectures are OK, I've tried deleting derived data folder, reinstalling the pods, setting Build Active Architectures Only to YES and NO, but nothing works.

My Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
workspace 'Purple'
target 'Purple' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
pod 'SAMKeychain', '~> 1.3'
pod 'TSMessages'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.23.2'
pod 'SWTableViewCell'
pod 'CardIO'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'PureLayout'
pod 'Branch'
pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
end
```

Comment: can you show ur podfile

Comment: I've added the podfile in the question.

Comment: try this `pod AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'` and `pod install` , for more referece see this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking.podspec

Comment: try to update the pods

Comment: I have updated the pods, but I have to keep the older version of AFNetworking because of some old code. The issue is not just with AFNetworking as you can see.

Comment: add use_frameworks! in pod file

Answer (score 9):

Try clear the XCode caches:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Clear the CocoaPods caches and reinstall the dependencies:

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update
```

Finally go to the "Pods" project and set the Build Active Architectures Only to No also for the "Debug" configuration.

Reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37930840/1773009

Comment: This helped me: Finally go to the "Pods" project and set the Build Active Architectures Only to No also for the "Debug" configuration.

Answer (score 2):

"The OPN [Debug] target overrides the OTHER_LDFLAGS build setting". This was the main issue. After adding $(inherited) in new line in other linker flags solved my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use below pod code.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘9.0’
use_frameworks!

target “NoteCheck” do

    pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => ‘4.0.1’
    pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator',    '~> 2.0'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper',        '~> 4.0.0'
    pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage',   '~> 1.2'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'         ,:git => 'https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.git'
    pod 'Reachability',             '~> 3.2'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON',               '~> 3.0.0'
    pod 'ObjectMapper' ,            '~> 2.0'
    pod 'SDWebImage',               '~> 3.8'

    pod 'SZTextView',               '~> 1.2'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding',           '~> 1.3'
    pod 'FXBlurView' ,              '~> 1.6.4'
    pod 'AMSmoothAlert',            '~> 1.0'

    pod 'DGElasticPullToRefresh',       '~> 1.1'
end
```

//Some of the  cocoapod library support minimum IO9.0 Support. So try min deployment target to 9.0 and check all cocoapod swift3.0 supported library. after editing pod file, update pod.

Comment: for swift, we should use Alamofire. or you can also use AFNetworking.

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue.