# Arm 64 support - archive failed

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I am enabling arm64 in my application, when i am archiving then no error comes but its showing archive failed.

Following is the my build settings -

[image]

And Deployment target is - 7.1.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created new project using Xcode 6.3 and imported all codes and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard to get rid of **arm64** for the time being. all you need to do is to:

- Edit your **target's Build Settings**. Change the value for
  **Architectures** by opening the drop down, click on **Other**... and select it, delete the row with value **$(ARCHS_STANDARD)** and add
  two rows with values: **armv7** and **armv7s** (or
  **$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)** as mentioned by **nschum**), close the popup.
- Edit the value **Valid Architectures** and simply remove the
  **arm64** part of it.
- Do it for every nested project you might have inside your workspace
  or project.

**Note:** This is not a solution, it's just a few steps to mitigate your current problem, please keep following your dependency projects to find out when they come with arm64 compatibility and revert these settings' change ASAP.

[image]

Comment: I need to support arm64 because i am uploading app with extensions so its required to support arm64.

Comment: Instead of setting Architectures to armv7 and armv7s, you can set it to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

Comment: No Luck, same result.

Comment: it will work natively on any 64Bit iDevice. you see, almost every 64Bit processor runs 32Bit apps because of backward compatibility, otherwise when the 64 bit devices were introduced, they could have ran none of the apps on the App Store... anyway, you can always make sure by running your app in Simulator for iPad iOS 7 (64bit)

Comment: Refer this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64