# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestSerializer"

Tags: swift, skmaps

I integrated the SDKTools via CocoaPods, with `use_frameworks!` and it is throwing me these errors:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTDownloadObjectHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkReachabilityManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTDownloadManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAdvisorSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Factories.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAnimationSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+UI.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAnnotation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+UI.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Styles.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKMapViewStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationConfiguration.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKMapsService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTDownloadManager+Additions.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTDownloadObjectHelper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKNavigationSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPositionerService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+BackgroundMode.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Factories.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+NavigationState.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+UI.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationUtils.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKReverseGeocoderService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationUtils.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKRouteSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Factories.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKRoutingService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+BackgroundMode.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+NavigationState.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Settings.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Styles.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+UI.o
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKTrailSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKVisualAdviceConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SKTNavigationManager+Factories.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Without the `use_frameworks!` flag, everything works fine. But I have to use this flag in order to use other pods.
This is a swift project btw.

Any help is highly appreciated since I've been trying to solve this for days now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64)?

Comment: Possibly. I "solved" it by integrating the sdk into a fresh project without cocoapods

Comment: Glad to hear that. I suggest you to answer to your own question and mark it as the accepted solution - that would help other devs having the same problem

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that this is the actual solution since all I was doing is starting with a fresh project and then implementing the sdk as binaries all over again. I don't think that counts as the solution. It certainly is A solution but not quite the best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

I did it using cocoapods like this:

```
cd /project/path
touch myPodfile
```

Now open your Podfile and add:

```
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
```

Then:

```
pod setup

pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the same issue and what solved for me was to run:

```
pod integrate
pod install
```

Basically a new install of the pods.