# Google CloudMessage for ios compile error

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I wrote it according to the official demo, then compile executable, appeared the following error

[image]

Comment: Please post actual error messages instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64

Comment: Did you install the Cocoapods? Did you make sure to open the Xcode workspace, not the Xcode project?