# undefined symbol error and mussing 64 bit support

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, arm64

Okay so, I get an undefined symbol error if I have 'arm64' in my valid architectures, and it goes away when I remove it. But, then when I try submitting the app to the app store without the 'arm64' I get the 'Missing 64 bit support' error.
This is extremely annoying and I have no clue what to do!

Comment: No. You shouldn't remove `arm64` from Valid Architectures. Instead, you should find out which library lacks `arm64` support. That library may require updates.

Comment: It's an [Apple requirement](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04082015a) that started 1st June 2015.

Comment: please refer bellow link it will help for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64