# Podfile error: Undefined Symbols for Architecture arm64

Tags: ios, architecture, cocoapods, arm64

I updated my cocoapods version to 1.0 and am now getting a slew of errors regarding architecture.  This is what my errors look like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ReachabilityManager.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ReachabilityManager)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PBJVision", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NewSpinViewController.o
  "_PBJVisionPhotoImageKey", referenced from:
      -[NewSpinViewController vision:capturedPhoto:error:] in NewSpinViewController.o
  "_kReachabilityChangedNotification", referenced from:
      -[NoInternetViewController viewDidLoad] in NoInternetViewController.o
  "_PBJVisionPhotoThumbnailKey", referenced from:
      -[NewSpinViewController vision:capturedPhoto:error:] in NewSpinViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've spent hours trying to fix this by toggling settlings under build settings but nothing is working for me.

This is what I currently have for my Architectures

[image]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64)

Comment: @Notlikethat I have literally tried everything in your linked post and nothing has fixed the problem...

Answer (score 2):

Try this: delete derived data and compile again. Sometimes the pod libraries simply don't get compiled even you cleaned the project, this happened to me when I updated to `cocoapods 1.0.1`.