# Apple Mach-O Linker Error -- Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker

I am getting a Apple Mach-O Linker Error every time I run my project, I'm trying to build using iPhone 6s with iOS 10.0.

Undefined symbols for architecture `arm64`:

```
"boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const", referenced from:
      boost::date_time::month_formatter<boost::gregorian::greg_month, boost::date_time::iso_format<char>, char>::format_month(boost::gregorian::greg_month const&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in libSHP.a(Timer.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using Xcode version 8.1

Comment: Try cleaning your project with CMD + Shift + k. Then try again.

Comment: @ankit Not working , I even try deleting the derived data and build the project again , but its not working

Comment: It might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64

Comment: Make sure the used boost lib is build for arm64.

Comment: @shallowThought  How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you link to a (sample) project showing the issue, to be able to have a look on your settings?

Answer (score 0):

If your **Architectures** and **Valid Architectures** are all right, you may check whether you have add `$(inherited)` to **Other Linker Flags** as below.