# xamarin ios build error at device mode

Tags: ios, xamarin, build

It's all fine in the simulator mode, but error in the device mode.
All libs have the arm64 and armv7.
I'll post the build log at the second layer.

Hello every one I had solved this issue.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: 
658 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LBBannerKit", referenced from: 
659 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
660 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDAutoLayoutLib", referenced from: 
661 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
662 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView_ViewController", referenced from: 
663 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
664 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView_ViewFrameGeometry", referenced from: 
665 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
666 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZYBannerViewLib", referenced from: 
667 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
668 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_slideNav", referenced from: 
669 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
670 1>       (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_slideNavBinding_SlideHeadView_SlideHeadViewAppearance
```

found that the names for example `LBBannerKit` in my binding project's apidefinition file which is no content in this class ,so I guess it's no use in the library,because this bingding api content is base on my xcode static library project.
so I remove the `LBBannerKit` class

another problem is that I remove the `[Category]` attribute in the `UIView_ViewController` and `UIView_ViewFrameGeometry` method .
It's no call in my project now so ,it's fine to compile in the simulator mode,and throw error in the device mode.

What happy is that after I solve all the issue above that error.
And build Successful!

Comment: https://github.com/jingliancui/XamarinIOSBuildLog/blob/master/TextFile1.txt

Comment: above link in GitHub is the build log from vs2015

Comment: was the checkbox, copy if needed checked when you copied the library in your project.

Comment: You need  to do these things in build settings : 1 . In Architectures select standard architectures 2. In Valid Architectures add arm7, arm7s, arm64 3. you have add $(inherited) to Other Linker Flags.

Comment: @KKRocks hello,in the vs ,where to find the "standard architecutres"?

Comment: in project target's build settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello every one I had solved this issue.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: 
658 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LBBannerKit", referenced from: 
659 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
660 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDAutoLayoutLib", referenced from: 
661 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
662 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView_ViewController", referenced from: 
663 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
664 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView_ViewFrameGeometry", referenced from: 
665 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
666 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZYBannerViewLib", referenced from: 
667 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
668 1>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_slideNav", referenced from: 
669 1>        objc-class-ref in registrar.o 
670 1>       (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_slideNavBinding_SlideHeadView_SlideHeadViewAppearance
```

found that the names for example `LBBannerKit` in my binding project's apidefinition file which is no content in this class ,so I guess it's no use in the library,because this bingding api content is base on my xcode static library project.
so I remove the `LBBannerKit` class

another problem is that I remove the `[Category]` attribute in the `UIView_ViewController` and `UIView_ViewFrameGeometry` method .
It's no call in my project now so ,it's fine to compile in the simulator mode,and throw error in the device mode.

What happy is that after I solve all the issue above that error.
And build Successful!