# Bug linking for archiving in app store (React Native App)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, archive

I get the following error that i can neither understand nor google when archiving for the app store (development deployment on device/emulator is functioning):

The App is in React Native Framework.

It could be related to HockeyApp since that was the last changes that I made developing.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_YGFloatIsUndefined", referenced from:
      ___74-[RCTShadowText applyLayoutToChildren:viewsWithNewFrame:absolutePosition:]_block_invoke in libRCTText.a(RCTShadowText.o)
      -[RCTShadowText _attributedStringWithFontFamily:fontSize:fontWeight:fontStyle:letterSpacing:useBackgroundColor:foregroundColor:backgroundColor:opacity:] in libRCTText.a(RCTShadowText.o)
  "_YGNodeGetContext", referenced from:
      _RCTMeasure in libRCTText.a(RCTShadowText.o)
  "_RCTSharedApplication", referenced from:
      -[RCTLinkingManager openURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
      -[RCTLinkingManager canOpenURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_RCTSizeInPixels", referenced from:
      _RCTDecodeImageWithData in libRCTImage.a(RCTImageUtils.o)
  "_RCTErrorUnspecified", referenced from:
      -[RCTLinkingManager openURL:resolve:reject:] in libRCTLinking.a(RCTLinkingManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTBundleURLProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_RCTImageFromLocalAssetURL", referenced from:
      ___119-[RCTLocalAssetImageLoader loadImageForURL:size:scale:resizeMode:progressHandler:partialLoadHandler:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in libRCTImage.a(RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.o)
  "_YGNodeStyleGetWidth", referenced from:
      ___74-[RCTShadowText applyLayoutToChildren:viewsWithNewFrame:absolutePosition:]_block_invoke in libRCTText.a(RCTShadowText.o)
      -[RCTShadowText _attributedStringWithFontFamily:fontSize:fontWeight:fontStyle:letterSpacing:useBackgroundColor:foregroundColor:backgroundColor:opacity:] in libRCTText.a(RCTShadowText.o)
  "_YGNodeStyleGetHeight", referenced from:
      ___74-[RCTShadowText applyLayoutToChildren:viewsWithNewFrame:absolutePosition:]_block_invoke in libRCTText.a(RCTShadowText.o)
      -[RCTShadowText _attributedStringWithFontFamily:fontSize:fontWeight:fontStyle:letterSpacing:useBackgroundColor:foregroundColor:backgroundColor:opacity:] in libRCTText.a(RCTShadowText.o)
  "_RCTIsMainQueue", referenced from:
      ___118-[RCTImageLoader _loadImageOrDataWithURLRequest:size:scale:resizeMode:progressBlock:partialLoadBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke in libRCTImage.a(RCTImageLoader.o)
      ___80-[RCTImageLoader decodeImageData:size:scale:clipped:resizeMode:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2 in libRCTImage.a(RCTImageLoader.o)
  "_YGNodeSetMeasureFunc", referenced from:
      -[RCTShadowText init] in libRCTText.a(RCTShadowText.o)
  "_RCTIsLocalAssetURL", referenced from:
      -[RCTLocalAssetImageLoader canLoadImageURL:] in libRCTImage.a(RCTLocalAssetImageLoader.o)
      -[RCTFileRequestHandler canHandleRequest:] in libRCTNetwork.a(RCTFileRequestHandler.o)
  "_RCTPresentedViewController", referenced from:
      -[RCTActionSheetManager showActionSheetWithOptions:callback:] in libRCTActionSheet.a(RCTActionSheetManager.o)
      -[RCTActionSheetManager showShareActionSheetWithOptions:failureCallback:successCallback:] in libRCTActionSheet.a(RCTActionSheetManager.o)
      ___47-[ImagePickerManager ....
```

Please tell me what additional information I should provide you with.

Regards

Comment: Did you try solutions of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64 ?

Comment: Hi there, i actually cannot find the variable in Xcode.

Comment: I tried now. The *architectures* and *valid architectures* seem to be all right, also the $inherited flag is set (although I don't know what I am doing here), so yes. Also it compiled and archived ok before, but thank you anyway.

Comment: did you found a solution for your problem? I'm facing the same issues :-(

Comment: Hi there, I don't quite remember but I think I either created a new React Native project or the problem was lying in the Cocoa Pods: Just remove them, as they double the React Native libs.