# "How to fix 'linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'?"

Tags: swift, xcode, sdk, structure

I want to build very simple code using Structure SDK. However, I get an error (see below)

Code :

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if (myclass.isConnected() == true){
            myTextView.text = "Exist."
        }
        else{
            myTextView.text = "Not Exist!"
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

    var myclass = STSensorController()
}
```

Error:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_STSensorController", referenced from:
>       objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

Please help me debug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64)

Answer (score 1):

Clean code with this command **shift** + **option** + **command** + **k**. If this fail, make sure your **STSensorController** class have reference in module.

Comment: Did you mean not ‘swift’ but ‘shift’? Also, can you explain more about “Make sure your STSensorController class have reference in module.”? I also think that there is a problem about STSensorController...