# Xcode Archive build failed with react native project

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

Latest react / react-native update.
Never had problem deploying my app to the appleStore since this morning.
Been struggling with this for hours. Here is the error message I get when I try to Product->Archive:

```
Ld /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/LesSherpas.build/Release-iphoneos/LesSherpas.build/Objects-normal/arm64/LesSherpas normal arm64 (in target: LesSherpas)
    cd /Users/angeliquesherpa/Terry/sherpas_mobile_app/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -L/Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/LesSherpas.build/Release-iphoneos/LesSherpas.build/Objects-normal/arm64/LesSherpas.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/LesSherpas.build/Release-iphoneos/LesSherpas.build/Objects-normal/arm64/LesSherpas_lto.o -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/LesSherpas.app/LesSherpas -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lc++ /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTBlob.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTAnimation.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libReact.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTActionSheet.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTGeolocation.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTImage.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTLinking.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTNetwork.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTSettings.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTText.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTVibration.a /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a -lRNVectorIcons -lRNImagePicker -lRCTOneSignal -lFastImage -lRNGestureHandler -lBVLinearGradient -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/LesSherpas.build/Release-iphoneos/LesSherpas.build/Objects-normal/arm64/LesSherpas_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/angeliquesherpa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LesSherpas-exmzjsfkzoxzwcehsbzxjyhztxsa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LesSherpas/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/LesSherpas.build/Release-iphoneos/LesSherpas.build/Objects-normal/arm64/LesSherpas

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_JSObjectGetPrototype", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectSetPrototype", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSPropertyNameAccumulatorAddName", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::getPropertyNames(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSPropertyNameAccumulator*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectCopyPropertyNames", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSContextGetGlobalObject", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::global() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeString", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsNumber", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSClassCreate", referenced from:
      void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::$_0&&> >(void*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::$_1&&> >(void*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectGetPropertyAtIndex", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getValueAtIndex(facebook::jsi::Array const&, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectMakeArray", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createArray(unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSEvaluateScript", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsUndefined", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSPropertyNameArrayGetCount", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSPropertyNameArrayGetNameAtIndex", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSPropertyNameArrayRelease", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeUndefined", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::getProperty(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSString*, OpaqueJSValue const**) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::call(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSValue*, unsigned long, OpaqueJSValue const* const*, OpaqueJSValue const**) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeNull", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::makeStringValue(OpaqueJSString*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createPropNameIDFromAscii(char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createPropNameIDFromUtf8(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createStringFromUtf8(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::(anonymous namespace)::getLengthString() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      ...
  "_JSObjectSetProperty", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::setPropertyValue(facebook::jsi::Object&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::setPropertyValue(facebook::jsi::Object&, facebook::jsi::String const&, facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createArray(unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectHasProperty", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::hasProperty(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::String const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::hasProperty(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_kJSClassDefinitionEmpty", referenced from:
      void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::$_0&&> >(void*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      void std::__1::__call_once_proxy<std::__1::tuple<facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::$_1&&> >(void*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectIsFunction", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::isFunction(facebook::jsi::Object const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsBoolean", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsInstanceOfConstructor", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::instanceOf(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::Function const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsObjectOfClass", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::isHostObject(facebook::jsi::Object const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::isHostFunction(facebook::jsi::Function const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueToNumber", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSGlobalContextRelease", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::~JSCRuntime() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCRuntime() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueToBoolean", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsArray", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::isArray(facebook::jsi::Object const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeNumber", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createArray(unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectSetPrivate", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::finalize(OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::finalize(OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsNull", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectSetPropertyAtIndex", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::setValueAtIndexImpl(facebook::jsi::Array&, unsigned long, facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsObject", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueMakeBoolean", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::valueRef(facebook::jsi::Value const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueUnprotect", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCObjectValue::invalidate() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueToStringCopy", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectGetProperty", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getProperty(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::String const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getProperty(facebook::jsi::Object const&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueToObject", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectGetPrivate", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getHostObject(facebook::jsi::Object const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::getHostFunction(facebook::jsi::Function const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::finalize(OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::getProperty(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSString*, OpaqueJSValue const**) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::setProperty(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSString*, OpaqueJSValue const*, OpaqueJSValue const**) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>)::HostObjectProxy::getPropertyNames(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*, OpaqueJSPropertyNameAccumulator*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      ...
  "_JSGlobalContextRetain", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCRuntime(OpaqueJSContext*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringRelease", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::evaluateJavaScript(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCStringValue::invalidate() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createPropNameIDFromAscii(char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createPropNameIDFromUtf8(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>)::HostFunctionMetadata::initialize(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringIsEqual", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::compare(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::strictEquals(facebook::jsi::String const&, facebook::jsi::String const&) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringGetMaximumUTF8CStringSize", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::(anonymous namespace)::JSStringToSTLString(OpaqueJSString*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectCallAsFunction", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::call(facebook::jsi::Function const&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringGetUTF8CString", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::(anonymous namespace)::JSStringToSTLString(OpaqueJSString*) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueProtect", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::makeObjectValue(OpaqueJSValue*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSValueIsString", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createValue(OpaqueJSValue const*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSStringRetain", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::makeStringValue(OpaqueJSString*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectMake", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::makeObjectValue(OpaqueJSValue*) const in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createObject(std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::HostObject>) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::createFunctionFromHostFunction(facebook::jsi::PropNameID const&, unsigned int, std::__1::function<facebook::jsi::Value (facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long)>) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSGlobalContextCreateInGroup", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::JSCRuntime() in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
  "_JSObjectCallAsConstructor", referenced from:
      facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::callAsConstructor(facebook::jsi::Function const&, facebook::jsi::Value const*, unsigned long) in libReact.a(JSCRuntime.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

react-native run-ios build also fails with the following error:

```
The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    Analyze /Users/angeliquesherpa/Terry/sherpas_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
    Analyze /Users/angeliquesherpa/Terry/sherpas_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTImageCache.m normal x86_64
    Analyze /Users/angeliquesherpa/Terry/sherpas_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetInfo.m normal x86_64
    AnalyzeShallow /Users/angeliquesherpa/Terry/sherpas_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native-fast-image/ios/Vendor/SDWebImage/Vendors/libwebp/src/enc/analysis_enc.c normal x86_64
    AnalyzeShallow /Users/angeliquesherpa/Terry/sherpas_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native-fast-image/ios/Vendor/SDWebImage/Vendors/FLAnimatedImage/FLAnimatedImage/FLAnimatedImageView.m normal x86_64
    AnalyzeShallow /Users/angeliquesherpa/Terry/sherpas_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native-fast-image/ios/Vendor/SDWebImage/Vendors/FLAnimatedImage/FLAnimatedImage/FLAnimatedImage.m normal x86_64
(6 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/angeliquesherpa/Terry/sherpas_mobile_app/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LesSherpas.app/LesSherpas normal x86_64
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LesSherpas.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LesSherpas.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist


Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LesSherpas.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:618:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:636:13)
    at Promise.then (/Users/angeliquesherpa/Terry/sherpas_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:208:5)
```

But the app actually starts on emulator...

I tried to downgrade react-native to prior version, delete .rncache, rm -rf node_modules, react-native start --reset-cache, clean build project, delete ios/build, and the combination of all of the above.

Comment: What version where you on before you upgraded and what version did you upgrade to?

Comment: It was 0.57.8. Now I'm using 0.58.5

Comment: What steps did you take to perform the upgrade?

Comment: npm i react-native@x.x.x --save

Answer (score 39):

Just updating the version of `react-native` is not enough when it comes to upgrading a `react-native` application. There are other changes to other files that must be made before the upgrade process is complete.

A good place to start is to look at the differences between the code in `0.57.8` and `0.58.5`. You can find these changes by looking at the git diff on `rn-diff-purge`. If you look at the following link you will see that there are a lot more changes than just version of `react-native`.

https://github.com/pvinis/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.57.8...version/0.58.5

Alternatively you can use the community upgrade helper

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.57.8&to=0.58.5

This has the added benefit of including links to upgrade tutorials (for some versions) and links to the changelog

Some of these changes will be superfluous and may not actually affect the running on the application, other changes will be critical and must be done. Unfortunately the git diff doesn't tell us which we must do and which we can miss out it just tells us the differences. My advice would be to make all the changes that it suggests.

It can also be beneficial to look at vanilla versions of the app that you are starting from and then moving to. You can create a react-native app at a specific version using the following code:

`react-native init newproject --version react-native@0.57.8`

Between react-native `0.57.8` and `0.58.5` there is one big change that was added in the Xcode project is that you have to add `JavaScriptCore.Framework` to the **Linked FrameWorks and Libraries**

[image: add JavaScriptCore.framework image]

It can be tricky to figure that one out from the git diff above.

Comment: So many hours spent trying to fix this issue - this answer worked for me!

Comment: Xcode lists JavaScriptCore.framework as 'iOS 12.2' when adding it. Would that mean I'll have a minimum target of iOS 12.2 with the updated version of React?

Comment: @Andrew Re "My advice would be to make all the changes that it suggests."
From the diffs shown in https://github.com/pvinis/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.57.8...version/0.58.5
I don't know how to interpret what changes they're suggesting making. Can you give me some guidance on that?

Comment: @gkeenley when reading a git diff it shows you the changes to each file. For each file it shows you what has been added (in green) and what has been removed (in red). You just perform the changes following that pattern to the files that it tells you. If you are still stuck I suggest asking another question as going through how to use git in the comments is not the correct place for such a big topic.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your quick reply. I don't think I need too much info so I won't open a new questions for now, but to make sure I understand what you said, do you just look through the changes and intuit what changes you might need to make based on that? In the changes at that link there are a bunch of references to "JavaScriptCore.framework in Frameworks". So did you see stuff like that and think "JavascriptCore isn't in my linked frameworks, I should add it"?

Comment: @Andrew awesome answer and great explanation! I are missing some good Xcode explanations, feel free to reach out to me or directly on https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-helper if you are up for some open source help :D.

Comment: @gkeenley For now, yes, that is the way. The Xcode project file diff is not great, and it needs experience to be interpreted easily, but basically yes, you need to see what is added or removed, and then go to Xcode and do the change that will cause a diff like the one in the upgrade-helper. This requires some familiarity with Xcode. Many people have done talks about this, and I am playing around with a way to replace this part and make the Xcode project file into a lock file basically, so the end-user (you) will not need to do any Xcode messing around.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that here someone expose an analogous question [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64), maybe it can help you