# react-native - linking fails after upgrade : ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, react-native, linker

i recently upgraded the react-native version with

```
react-native upgrade
```

and followed all steps without any errors so far.
Now when i want to build the ios Version i get following Error:

```
❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

```
Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CustomName.app/CustomName normal x86_64
```

(1 failure)

```
The following commands produced analyzer issues:
Analyze Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
Analyze RCTNetInfo.m normal x86_64
Analyze RCTImageCache.m normal x86_64
(3 commands with analyzer issues)
```

My Project Env

`React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.3
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
      Memory: 140.02 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 11.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3 
      react-native: 0.58.5 => 0.58.5 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
      react-native-rename: 2.4.0`

So i checked to folder

```
build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/
```

and could find an .app file which was disabled by System ( other react-native projects have a valid .app file )

So it seems like that the build is creating an invalid .app file which then ( understandable ) fails linking since the file / folder is not available.

Is there any chance to get a detailed insight what is causing this invalid .app file and how to fix it?

Any Hint is appreciated!

Comment: I'm having no luck with the answers to this question. Just wondering if you did manage to find a fix for this problem?

Comment: `arch -x86_64 yarn iOS`

Answer (score 9):

[Xcode Archive build failed with react native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843771/xcode-archive-build-failed-with-react-native-project)

The first answer about `JavaScriptCore.framework` save my life, hope helped : )

Answer (score 7):

If you have a Mac with an M1 chip, then the solution is:

```
arch -x86_64 yarn ios
```

Comment: this worked for me even I don't have a M1 Mac yet.

Comment: Spent hours trying to find a way to get rid of this error, this was the solution ! I added the `arch -x86_64` to my package.json scripts! works with XCode 14.2

Answer (score 3):

You should add `JavaScriptCore.Framework` to `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary With Libraries`.