# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 (realm)

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

I'm using realm in my react-native project: https://github.com/kdnakt/pixelarn

After [running `ncu -u`](https://github.com/kdnakt/pixelarn/commit/c26f76b3413fd2136bd4cc268c312867a150e3ae) on my Mac to update react-native-elements to 1.0.0 and realm to 2.23.0, `react-native run-ios` would not start my app and I'm getting the following error:

```
  realm::jsc::ObjectWrap<realm::js::CollectionClass<realm::jsc::Types> >::create_class() in libRealmReact.a(jsc_init.o)
  ...
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ** BUILD FAILED **
```

I saw some Github issues and tried `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and `rm -rf ios/build/` in my project directory, but still failing ... how can I start my react native app with `react-native run-ios`?

Comment: same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

There was some modifications after upgrade to react native 0.58.5 and above versions.

[Xcode Archive build failed with react native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843771/xcode-archive-build-failed-with-react-native-project)

Try to manually link the JavaScriptCore.framework in "Link Binary With Libraries". I had the same problem and it work for me.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fyTO.png)