# How to fix clang error: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob, arm64

I been trying to build an app through Xcode and I keep getting this error: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64. I just built another app with the same setup using unity 2018.3.2.f1 and I did not get this issue.

I tried to go through my unity project to see if any duplicate files were generated, but no luck.

### Xcode Error:

> ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/derrickdandin/Desktop/Jumpy_Animal_Friends - iOS/Jumpy_Jump_Friends_iOS/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginGetCurrentSeekPercent", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginGetCurrentSeekPercent_m33BEF11BEC3ECF2CA7749FDEB8053842617D5263 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginGetCurrentSeekPercent_m33BEF11BEC3ECF2CA7749FDEB8053842617D5263)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginSetAudioTrack", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetAudioTrack_m3B5D1193719F527FE2B4191D359CA7CC415B869C in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetAudioTrack_m3B5D1193719F527FE2B4191D359CA7CC415B869C)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginSetSpeed", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetSpeed_m544F96C52FD70D09738A3EB448DF5FEF3499D365 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetSpeed_m544F96C52FD70D09738A3EB448DF5FEF3499D365)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginFinish", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginFinish_mA49DFCE2D3998099D5B6BA6071D83CDA59F0C65E in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginFinish_mA49DFCE2D3998099D5B6BA6071D83CDA59F0C65E)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginSetTexture", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetTexture_mFA4886828CE828667D4C37ABC4F4077848251AD0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetTexture_mFA4886828CE828667D4C37ABC4F4077848251AD0)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginStopVideo", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginStopVideo_m12AD66699F6E4976AF0A73A9BEEA15A3B19C4BC7 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginStopVideo_m12AD66699F6E4976AF0A73A9BEEA15A3B19C4BC7)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginCurTimeSeconds", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCurTimeSeconds_m06A7AFEA2189163B334238B75674A76F9B4D6845 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCurTimeSeconds_m06A7AFEA2189163B334238B75674A76F9B4D6845)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginSeekToVideo", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSeekToVideo_mE8CC13E1AF6EE2D83DEE456CE70F21D9763DDDCC in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSeekToVideo_mE8CC13E1AF6EE2D83DEE456CE70F21D9763DDDCC)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginRewindVideo", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginRewindVideo_mA26C3B76B74B103A4A43813EFFEB66DF1C91C2E1 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginRewindVideo_mA26C3B76B74B103A4A43813EFFEB66DF1C91C2E1)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginResumeVideo", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginResumeVideo_m7D33CEAE27D87DA22B1B3364FB9C456EE58D2DD7 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginResumeVideo_m7D33CEAE27D87DA22B1B3364FB9C456EE58D2DD7)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginSetVolume", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetVolume_m16B65D08C90C128FD82A8D6A9F0CD6190C7B3ECE in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetVolume_m16B65D08C90C128FD82A8D6A9F0CD6190C7B3ECE)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginError", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginError_m19CDF508403F3828DF714032DFFADA280BFD0107 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginError_m19CDF508403F3828DF714032DFFADA280BFD0107)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginIsPlaying", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginIsPlaying_m57B48F3CC9EBD56D2B151FF3C44679BE160D626C in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginIsPlaying_m57B48F3CC9EBD56D2B151FF3C44679BE160D626C)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginGetAudioTrack", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginGetAudioTrack_m102B7410AAC4851718AD27C380AF78610E7D29CA in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginGetAudioTrack_m102B7410AAC4851718AD27C380AF78610E7D29CA)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginDurationSeconds", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginDurationSeconds_mBA1A824E1A9FCFA82ACAEA3B987E446618366E89 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginDurationSeconds_mBA1A824E1A9FCFA82ACAEA3B987E446618366E89)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginPlayVideo", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPlayVideo_m21557D326D89BB4038C78162FBF4BE333357D13F in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPlayVideo_m21557D326D89BB4038C78162FBF4BE333357D13F)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginCurFrameTexture", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCurFrameTexture_m6E9884E2FBFBA0EECB1502F4348E8CF0EBB045EE in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCurFrameTexture_m6E9884E2FBFBA0EECB1502F4348E8CF0EBB045EE)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginLoadVideo", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginLoadVideo_m9BBB66F654483B414D09FF6CD3EF0B324F209CA5 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginLoadVideo_m9BBB66F654483B414D09FF6CD3EF0B324F209CA5)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginPlayerReady", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPlayerReady_m1BBFA30E280506830C6B7CABB5719B80D2A5BD17 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPlayerReady_m1BBFA30E280506830C6B7CABB5719B80D2A5BD17)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginPauseVideo", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPauseVideo_m365AED7AE6922CE4D3BF11BA3A3AB3E45BA55D2E in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginPauseVideo_m365AED7AE6922CE4D3BF11BA3A3AB3E45BA55D2E)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginExtents", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginExtents_m02D4C687310EB53549AC6B13591894CC76048D92 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginExtents_m02D4C687310EB53549AC6B13591894CC76048D92)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginDestroyInstance", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginDestroyInstance_m404DBB6565D1BF7FD1F82F5D6A2E4CC7D1A8B065 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginDestroyInstance_m404DBB6565D1BF7FD1F82F5D6A2E4CC7D1A8B065)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginCanOutputToTexture", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCanOutputToTexture_m28EF7A2669AF7786E79594C48D0A7293EF7AD1B1 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCanOutputToTexture_m28EF7A2669AF7786E79594C48D0A7293EF7AD1B1)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginSetLoop", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetLoop_m198D76AA47FE3D5DE4362DA6BD83D2ABA3C6EFF3 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginSetLoop_m198D76AA47FE3D5DE4362DA6BD83D2ABA3C6EFF3)
>     "_VideoPlayerPluginCreateInstance", referenced from:
>         _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCreateInstance_m180D5B72D5B6CD5515C4B129CC6E05392AD145F4 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
>        (maybe you meant: _MediaPlayerCtrl_VideoPlayerPluginCreateInstance_m180D5B72D5B6CD5515C4B129CC6E05392AD145F4)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I made sure my project plugins folder was clear of any lingering old files, which there were old plugins that were still in there.