# Compile error for XCUITest for googleSignIn

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, xcuitest

I have configured GoogleSignIn using pod.

My pod file
target ‘MyApp’ do
      # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
      use_frameworks!

```
  # Pods for MyApp
    pod 'p2.OAuth2'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'p2.OAuth2'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  end
end
```

I am able to Sign In to google.
For **XCUITest**, I am getting error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Myclass.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In those classes I have imported "GoogleSignIn".

How do I solve this issue?

Bitcode is off, other liner flags -ObjC is added.

Comment: add these pods to test target in your podfile too.

Comment: I have already added for UItest target. updated pod detail in question

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked build setting for test target.

test target-> build setting -> other linker flags

I have added "-framework" and next to it "GoogleSignIn". It worked.