# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_FIRAuthStateDidChangeInternalNotificationAppKey", referenced from

Tags: ios, firebase, linker-errors

I am trying to update to latest frameworks in our app, but getting this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_FIRAuthStateDidChangeInternalNotificationAppKey", referenced from:
      -[FAuthStateListenerWrapper authStateDidChangeNotification:] in FirebaseDatabase(FAuthTokenProvider_6272866f5c75e14e01c4ca08384ffa05.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

this is how my pod file looks

```
platform :ios, “9.0”

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target "foo" do

pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'Ono'
pod 'AFOnoResponseSerializer'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'CTFeedback'
pod 'SIAlertView'
pod 'GPUImage'#, '~> 0.1.4'
pod 'UICKeyChainStore'
pod 'ASValueTrackingSlider'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'#, '~> 7.47.0'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'SSZipArchive'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase'#, '~> 4.8.2'
pod 'Firebase/Auth’
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Invites'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end
```

I just ran `pod update` and the error started to show up.

added -ObjC,-licucore in other linker flags, alao disabled bitcode.

Comment: Possible duplicate? Similar issue from here? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64)

Comment: looked into it already. tried those solutions, nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information here to completely tell what is going on, but here are two red flags:

1. The missing symbol is from `FirebaseDatabase`, but `FirebaseDatabase` is not listed in the Podfile.
2. `Firebase/Invites` is in the Podfile, but `Invites` is no longer part of Firebase and will force Firebase 5 to be installed instead of the current Firebase 6.

You can learn more about why certain dependencies are chosen by examining the `Podfile.lock`.

Comment: thanks. that did the trick. removed `Firebase/Invites` and added `Firebase/Database` in podfile.