# How to fix the "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:" error in Xcode after building a Unity project?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

In my Unity project I wanna use [Google Mobile Ads](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity) and when I build it for Xcode and try to launch on a device, I get the next error.

---

This is what I'm getting.
ld: warning: **arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /path_to_my_project/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o).
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:**.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64/28877558) that was already posted on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I had struggled with this issue too and turns out my problem was because my iPhone IOS version didn't match with the setting in the Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue with some of the latest versions of xcode, i solved it by doing the following:

- Install Xcode 9.3.1 (probably other older version will work as well)
- Go to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib  in the xcode 9.3.1 installation
- copy the libc++ and  libstdc++ libraries (there might be some other libraries im missing here, i did this a while ago)  over to the same place in your current xcode installation and restart the current xcode and try to build again.

hope this helps!