# cannot use Agora share screen example for ios

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io

i started using agora sdk for ios to implement video call with share screen

i followed the documentation till the point of adding :>
"
integrate the Agora Video SDK

Download the Agora Video SDK. Unzip the downloaded SDK package and copy the following files from the SDK libs folder into iOS&macOS/libs/iOS folder.

```
AograRtcKit.framework
AgoraRtcCryptoLoader.framework
libcrypto.a"
```

i tried so but xcode kept having errors while linking and running the project

```
errors :
1- Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AgoraVideoEncoderConfiguration
2- Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AgoraRtcEngineKit
3- Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AgoraVideoFrame
4- Undefined symbol: _AgoraVideoBitrateStandard
5- Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
```

i used some steps to fix this issues:

```
1- added (AgoraRtcEngineKit.framework

Accelerate.framework

AudioToolbox.framework

AVFoundation.framework

CoreMedia.framework

CoreML.framework

CoreTelephony.framework

libc++.tbd

libresolv.tbd

SystemConfiguration.framework

VideoToolbox.framework)

2- deleted (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/)for my current project 
3-added $(inherited) , which will add linker flags generated in pods, to Other Linker Flags 
as mentioned in [this link][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64
```

with no solution for this problem

looking forward to having answers for this issues

Comment: Did you find any solution yet ??

Comment: no , i have shifted my effort to Zoom SDK for both android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

What tutorial were you following there? If having problems with installing the frameworks manually cocoapods is a much more straightforward choice.

Also this repository has an example with screen share working in iOS, along with a few other examples provided by Agora:
https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples/tree/master/iOS