# Godot Project Has 100 Errors When Exported To Xcode [Arm64]

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, export, godot, gdscript

I have been learning how to use Godot and recently I tried to export my project to Xcode to see how my game would look on my phone. When I try to run it, it shows that there are exactly 100 errors.

The error code is huge!

```html
Ld /Users/tonymartini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wheel-hbetymftcixgfwcvonanonkkbxsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Wheel.app/Wheel normal (in target 'Wheel' from project 'Wheel')
    cd /Users/tonymartini/Desktop/Godot\ Round\ 2
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target arm64-apple-ios12.3 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk -L/Users/tonymartini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wheel-hbetymftcixgfwcvonanonkkbxsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/tonymartini/Desktop/Godot\ Round\ 2 -F/Users/tonymartini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wheel-hbetymftcixgfwcvonanonkkbxsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F. -FWheel -FWheel/dylibs -filelist /Users/tonymartini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wheel-hbetymftcixgfwcvonanonkkbxsz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Wheel.build/Debug-iphoneos/Wheel.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Wheel.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/tonymartini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wheel-hbetymftcixgfwcvonanonkkbxsz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Wheel.build/Debug-iphoneos/Wheel.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Wheel_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib\=libc++ -framework StoreKit /Users/tonymartini/Desktop/Godot\ Round\ 2/Wheel.a -framework GameKit -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/tonymartini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wheel-hbetymftcixgfwcvonanonkkbxsz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Wheel.build/Debug-iphoneos/Wheel.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Wheel_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/tonymartini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Wheel-hbetymftcixgfwcvonanonkkbxsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Wheel.app/Wheel

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_mono_get_exception_argument", referenced from:
      godot_icall_Array_CopyTo(Array*, _MonoArray*, int) in Wheel.a(collections_glue.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      godot_icall_Dictionary_Add(Dictionary*, _MonoObject*, _MonoObject*) in Wheel.a(collections_glue.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
  "_mono_get_exception_index_out_of_range", referenced from:
      godot_icall_Array_At(Array*, int) in Wheel.a(collections_glue.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      godot_icall_Array_At_Generic(Array*, int, unsigned int, GDMonoClass*) in Wheel.a(collections_glue.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      godot_icall_Array_SetAt(Array*, int, _MonoObject*) in Wheel.a(collections_glue.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      godot_icall_Array_Insert(Array*, int, _MonoObject*) in 
      ...
  "_mono_type_full_name", referenced from:
      GDMonoUtils::get_type_desc(_MonoType*) in 

I reached the character limit so I cut out the middle, let me know if you want it
  
      GDMono::get_class(_MonoClass*) in Wheel.a(gd_mono.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      GDMono::~GDMono() in Wheel.a(gd_mono.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      _GodotSharp::get_domain_id() in Wheel.a(gd_mono.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      CSharpLanguage::debug_get_current_stack_info() in Wheel.a(csharp_script.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      CSharpInstance::_internal_new_managed() in Wheel.a(csharp_script.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      CSharpScript::_create_instance(Variant const**, int, Object*, bool, Variant::CallError&) in Wheel.a(csharp_script.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
      ...
  "_mono_runtime_set_main_args", referenced from:
      GDMono::initialize() in Wheel.a(gd_mono.iphone.opt.debug.arm64.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Something I tried is talked about here: [Link](https://godotengine.org/qa/80475/cannot-build-xcode-project-after-exporting-for-ios). Basically, download visual studio and export Xamarin dylib to Xcode project. The problem with this, as left unsolved in the post, is that instead of the hundred errors, a single new error appears: 
`"Unresolved symbol: gdmonosetupaot"`

Comment: You may find the answers in this question helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64

Comment: @JarWarren I've looked at that before, the problem is that I don't know what libraries I'm missing. I don't know what I am doing wrong but exporting Godot projects to Xcode results in these 100 errors.