# React native 0.63.4 iOS Build failed

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm facing the below mentioned issue unable to run even new fresh code in react native.

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/rajkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lead-eglylsywnqcvohasboackklnitvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Lead.app/Lead normal x86_64
(1 failure)
```

I had followed this below steps but getting same error. Can any one please guide me to resolve this issue please

comment all flipper function in podfile
remove flipperInit in appDelegate
remove openSSl in podfile.lock
pod install,
clean project
run again

Comment: Try to clean build, and then run your project from xcode

Comment: I had tried this process, But unable to resolve the issue

Comment: Try to create an empty-project and see if it builds...

Comment: I'm getting same issue even after creating an empty project. Please find the below details  for the issue i'm getting.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow", referenced from:
      _RAND_poll in libcrypto.a(rand_unix.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: ** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/rajkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-cydiidwtvewpvtbgfkrsmhbrvyza/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Demo.app/Demo normal x86_64
(1 failure)

Comment: Please guide me to resolve this issue

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64