# Undefined symbol error after Xcode 13 update

Tags: react-native-ios, arm64, armv7, xcode13

I have recently updated my `Xcode` to `v13`. Since then when I tried to archive I am getting following error

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_UMAppDelegateWrapper
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UMAppDelegateWrapper
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UMModuleRegistryProvider
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UMModuleRegistryAdapter
```

If I run in simulator or real device, Then there is no error. Getting errors only when I tired to archiving.

I tried to apply what suggested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64). But there is no use.

Can someone help me to get rid of these errors?

Comment: After lot of struggle for a month I resolved this issue by increasing minimum iOS version from `iOS10` to `iOS11`

Answer (score 0):

There is a new library from Xcode 12 that needs to be added to the Link Binary with Libraries phase call **libSwiftWebKit.tbd**. This help me.

Go to the Xcode
**Build Phases** => **Link Binary With Libraries** => press **+** paste in search **libSwiftWebKit.tbd** => **Add**
[image]

Comment: I tired this solution and it's not working. Any alternative?