# XCode 6 CocoaPods error : target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I just starting using CocoaPods and I am getting the following errors when I pod install from the terminal (My project is called babyMilestones and I'm trying to use CocoaPods for the ShipLib Framework). :

> The `babyMilestones [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.

I'm getting this error for Header Search Paths and Framework Search Paths.

When I try to build my project I get an error on the #import line saying the ShipLib/ShipLib.h file cannot be found.  In my project navigator my Pods project is showing properly, and the ShipLib framework is visible.

I never set any of these search paths explicitly, I just let XCode 6 do it's thing.  I found this answer : [The target ... overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods)
I have tried the following :

1. Deleted all the Framework Search Paths in Build Settings.  This did not fix the issue 
   [image]
2. I then added $(inherited) to the Framework Search Path.  I did Clean then Build.  This gave new errors of the following type:

   > ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/billpaystation/Documents/iOS/babyMilestones/babyMilestones/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
   >   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F'
   >   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   >   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ActionSheetDatePicker", referenced from:
   >     objc-class-ref in EditItemViewController.o
   >   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SYSincerelyController", referenced from:
   >     objc-class-ref in EditItemViewController.o
   >   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
   >   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Action Sheet Picker and Sincerely Controller are the libraries I'm trying to add with Pods.

3. I noticed that libPods.a is red under Frameworks in my file inspector.  So I went to Scheme ->Edit Scheme-> and added Pods to the Build.  [image]
   I don't really understand the whole target/build settings and I may have made it worse trying so many different things.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should add $(inherited) to the Framework Search Path. Can you tell us what is the other errors after that step. Maybe you need to feel something in addition.

Comment: I updated my question with the linker errors I receive if I add $(inherited) to my frameworks search path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add $(inherited) to the Framework Search Path. For the new errors you should go:

TargetSettings->Build Phases->Compile Sources->(+) ActionSheetDatePicker.m, and SYSincerelyController.m classes and then Build and Run.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my problem and solution from yesterday.

[target overrides the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445784/target-overrides-the-framework-search-paths-build-settings)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was not an Xcode issue, plus I think that fixing it by hand is a bad idea. I tried to use a different (earlier version) of Cocoapods and it worked fine!

`gem install cocoapods -v 0.33.1`

Comment: Worked for me as well although my error was regarding `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` instead. Thanks!