# target overrides the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS build settings

Tags: cocoapods

I'd like to update the CocoaPods built into my app, so I ran `pod install` from the terminal.

That's when I got this error:

```
[!] The `APP_NAME [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

How do you **Use the $(inherited) flag?**

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Selected the Project, targets-> app, then `Build Settings` where I added the $(inherited) line, deleting whatever specific pod had been referenced there before:

[image]

Comment: Thx. I had to remove the pod that was specified and had to replace it with  $(inherited) you mentioned.

Comment: In my case, I need to add too $(PROJECT_DIR)

Comment: This answer was the end of a long, long search. Thank you for posting answer and comments.

Comment: Word of caution - I tried this solution, and though it did work for me, it created many other import issues that I had to resolve as well.  It was not clear until I finished, whether or not I made things worse or better.  Whoever reads this- stick with it and try to resolve the issues that this solution may make visible.

Comment: Hello, I added this in and it resolved my issue with `framework not found Mapbox` but then followed with errors of `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)` Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855382/mapbox-libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception

Comment: I am using Xcode 9.1 and nothing is mentioned under framework search paths. I simply added $(inherited) and build the project. And it worked !! Thanks @peter :)

Comment: I want to point out that the "non-recursive" in the $(inherited) property is important. When set to "recursive" this TARGET OVERIDES error will not be solved. Tested on Xcode 10.3.

Comment: I want to update the framework search path from terminal. Kindly help on that. Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 15):

I was encountering this issue as well.

Aside from doing what Peter mentioned above, remember to **double check if the correct Xcode project is selected in your podfile**. This is because it is possible that you are changing the Build Settings of the incorrect Xcode project. It was a silly mistake, but it took quite some time before I realized it.

Normally, `pod install` works automatically if there is only one `.xcodeproj` file in the directory. However, if you are migrating your project to begin using cocoapods from the old way of manually adding frameworks/3rd party projects to your Xcode project, it is possible that you will have multiple .xcodeproj files in your folder. Doing the abovementioned fix didn't solve it for me, because I was editing the incorrect `.xcodeproj` file.

Go to your project directory, check the file named `Podfile` and make sure you specify the `xcodeproj`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift

use_frameworks!
xcodeproj 'APP_NAME.xcodeproj'
target 'APP_NAME' do

# Your dependencies here
# pod 'NAME_OF_DEPENDENCY'
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 2.0'
pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 2.0'
pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

After selecting the correct `.xcodeproj` on your Podfile, go to Xcode and do the following:

1. From the Project Navigator on the left side, select your project.
2. On the center screen, go to `Build Settings`
3. Add a filter for 'Framework Search Paths'
4. Enter `$(inherited)` as the value; it should auto-fill with data evaluating that expression

Below is an image of Xcode with Version 7.2 (7C68).

[image: Xcode preview]

Comment: Just a note: CocoaPods 1.3.1 gives a deprecation warning: "`xcodeproj` was renamed to `project`. Please update your Podfile accordingly."

Answer (score 0):

I had a $(inherited) but recursive, just change it to non-recursive

project target -> build settings -> framework_search_path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem (error build: Framework not found Pods_xxx) when updating cordova-onesignal from v2 to 3.3.0 on an old Ionic 3 project.

**This solved it for me:**

In Xcode, navigate Project + Target + General + Scroll down to Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content

In the list I simply deleted (minus sign at bottom of list) the related file Pods_xxx.framework (it was a little grayed out)

After rebuild everything worked (incl OneSignal)

If I do pod install it comes back and I have to do it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

It helps for me as well! But when I run pod install library search paths overwrites.
So I made a hook for podfile, maybe it will help someone

```
project_path = './yourProject.xcodeproj' 
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)

project.targets.each do |target|
  if target.name == 'yourProjectTarget' 
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ['$(inherited)']
    end
  end
end

project.save
```

This hook overwrites **LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS** to **$(inherited)** for you each time you run **pod install**.
Place it inside post_install Podfile block