# CocoaPods update target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm useing CocoaPods for one year now within my iOS app.
Yesterday I tried to update `pod update` all the pods included in my project.

But when using this command I'm always getting this following error:

```
[!] The `XXXTests [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXXTests/Pods-XXXTests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `XXX [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXXTests/Pods-XXXTests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26445806/4543961) I have changed my FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS to `$(inherited)` but it does not effect anything.
[image]

Can anyone help me dealing with this problem?

EDIT 1: This is the content of my pod file:

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'xxx' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for xxx
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'


  target 'xxxTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'xxx' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  # Pods for xxx

   target 'xxxTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: edit ur pod file in textedit and replace with it my updated answer pod file. save textedit file , close  , fire commend pod install

Comment: Many thanks! :) But I also had to place `$(inherited)` in FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS for my target xxx AND xxxTests

Comment: Delete xxxTests

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghpZH.png)step 1 :-  delete only CocoaPods from your project not pod file.

step 2: - update $(inherited) at ur project Framework search path.

step 3: - fire commend again pod install.

here is pod file

## Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

## platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'DemoError' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  # Pods for DemoError

target 'DemoErrorTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but it does not change anything. I have deleted the 'Pods' folder and the 'Podfile.lock' but when typing 'pod install' again this error appears again.

Comment: I deleted everything except the pod file, but it effected just one thing. At first I got the error twice and now only once. But it still appears. I have added my pod file to the question ;)

Comment: it will work fine , no error show . here it pod file just check ur pod file with mine

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'DemoError' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  # Pods for DemoError

  target 'DemoErrorTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

Comment: just use after this line   use_frameworks!   pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'

Comment: just compare with my pod file image

Comment: Many thanks for all your answers. I tried to use your pod file configuration, but the error still occurs :/ I have also reinstalled cocoapods.

Comment: ur added pod file show wrong position of  these for line

Comment: pod 'Firebase'
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Crash'
 pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'