# ERROR import with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, cocoapods

**I just installed CocoaPods so I'll be able to import the Facebook SDK for Swift**

When I install the pod I got this warning:

[image: error]

> [!] The `MyAppName[Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-myappname/Pods-myappname.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

I already did all the solution listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445784/target-overrides-the-framework-search-paths-build-settings) post but didn't work for me.

When I use $(inherited) the field remain white:
[image: error2]

**And my Facebook import don't work:**

> No such module as 'FacebookCore'

Where is the problem? I'm going mad.

Here is my Pod file:

[image: error3]

EDIT FOR THE ANSWER:

I edited the file like that and run the command but got the same warning and my import still don't work:

[image: error4]

Comment: Please post the error in plain text as well: images are great for context but cannot be searched. The message _target overrides..._ would gain much in being in plain text in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for contributing, The only way I found that work is to re-create a new Project and start on from there.

Any work around didn't work for me.

Comment: Right - This was probably due to the missing \`$inherited`. You did the right thing: starting fresh is so much cleaner, faster and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

> Use the `$(inherited)` flag

1. Go to *project* > TARGETS > *target* > Build Settings
2. Search for FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS
3. add `$(inherited)` to each configuration

   [image: Adding the inherited flag]
4. Quit Xcode
5. `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`

---

If this fails, clean the configurations as well:

1. Go to *project* > PROJECT > Info > Configurations, select each one, one at a time (Debug, ApplicationUnitTest, Release, etc.), and for each target within said configuration, set configuration to `None`.
   Make certain that *Based on Configuration File* reads **0 Configurations Set**
2. Quit Xcode
3. `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`

Comment: I tried but got the same error, question updated for you