# framework not found Mapbox iOS Xcode React-Native

Tags: react-native, mapbox

I've been getting this error for a number of days whilst attempting to install and use [mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/ios/install.md) Whilst Mapbox works on Android, it does not work on iOS for me consistently resulting in an error on build which is `framework not found Mapbox`

When installing via CocoaPods I'm getting an error from xcode

```
framework not found Mapbox

Ld /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/clustr.app/clustr normal x86_64
    cd /Users/michaelstokes/clustr/clustr_app/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk -L/Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React -L/Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stripe -L/Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-mapbox-gl -L/Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yoga -F/Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/michaelstokes/Documents/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Clustr.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/clustr.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/clustr.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Clustr.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/clustr.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/clustr_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lReact -lStripe -lreact-native-mapbox-gl -lstdc++ -lyoga -framework AddressBook -framework Foundation -framework JavaScriptCore -framework Mapbox -framework PassKit -framework Security -framework WebKit -framework XCTest -weak_framework Contacts -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Clustr.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/clustr.build/clustr.app.xcent /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTAnimation.a -framework FBSDKLoginKit /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTActionSheet.a /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTGeolocation.a /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTImage.a /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTLinking.a /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTNetwork.a -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework Bolts /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTSettings.a /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTText.a /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTVibration.a -framework FBSDKCoreKit /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTWebSocket.a -lAirMaps -lRNDeviceInfo -lPods-clustr -lRCTCamera -lreact-native-branch -lRNGeocoder -lReact -lyoga -lcxxreact -ljschelpers -lRNVectorIcons -lTPSStripe -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Clustr.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/clustr.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/clustr_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clustr-fkpfvfogtttxepgdsdrkmamfpvax/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/clustr.app/clustr

ld: framework not found Mapbox
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
My podfile is as follows:

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'clustr' do

  # Flexbox Layout Manager Used By React Natve
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'

  # React Native
  pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
    # Comment out any unneeded subspecs to reduce bundle size.
    'Core',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTBlob',
    'RCTCameraRoll',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTPushNotification',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTTest',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTLinkingIOS'
  ]

  # Mapbox
  pod 'react-native-mapbox-gl', :path => '../node_modules/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl'

  pod 'Stripe', '~> 10.1.0'

  inherit! :search_paths
end
When running pod install I get

MacBook-Pro:ios michaelstokes$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `React` from `../node_modules/react-native`
Fetching podspec for `react-native-mapbox-gl` from `../node_modules/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl`
Fetching podspec for `yoga` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Using React (0.50.4)
Using Stripe (10.1.0)
Using react-native-mapbox-gl (6.0.1)
Using yoga (0.50.4.React)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 19 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 8.0 on target clustr because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] The `clustr [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-clustr/Pods-clustr.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `clustr [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-clustr/Pods-clustr.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Thanks very much!

I was getting framework not found Mapbox but after Following an answer over at [target overrides the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445784/target-overrides-the-framework-search-paths-build-settings) target overrides the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS build settings about adding `$(inherited)` to framework search paths that resolved it but then there were following issues on build relating to libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
`(lldb)`

Comment: Did you ever paste any plist files into the ios directory before?

Comment: Nope @ShaneG The issue is now related too ` libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` whenever including say the Mapbox mapview in the code. The issue is up to date over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855382/mapbox-libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception

Comment: Ok. This link might be handy https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/313

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue of `framework not found Mapbox` during build I had to add `$(inherited)` to framework search paths and then the build was succesfull but follows with an issue when trying to include Mapbox views so whilst this is a partial answer, it resolves the issue of `framework not found Mapbox` but then there are following issues over at [Mapbox: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855382/mapbox-libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error whilst installing it on a iOS Simulator, you'll have to add it in the `Framework Search Paths` (as mentioned above) - however, use the options for debug and release:

**Device**

> Any iOS SDK

**Simulator**

> Any iOS Simulator SDK

I put the first option into the Framework Search Paths, and the project built fine on a physical device. However, when I went to use it on a Simualtor, it failed - this is why.

Here is my path:

```
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios
```