# Mapbox: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: xcode, react-native, mapbox, react-native-ios

I've been implementing Mapbox as whilst working on Android, I get errors on iOS after installing via CocoaPods ... I was getting `framework not found Mapbox` but after Following an answer over at [target overrides the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445784/target-overrides-the-framework-search-paths-build-settings) about adding $(inherited) to framework search paths that resolved it but then there were following issues on build relating to `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

My podfile is as follows:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'clustr' do

  # Flexbox Layout Manager Used By React Natve
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'

  # React Native
  pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
    # Comment out any unneeded subspecs to reduce bundle size.
    'Core',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTBlob',
    'RCTCameraRoll',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTPushNotification',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTTest',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTLinkingIOS'
  ]

  # Mapbox
  pod 'react-native-mapbox-gl', :path => '../node_modules/@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl'

  pod 'Stripe', '~> 10.1.0'

  inherit! :search_paths
end


After running the build successfully, and after adding the following Mapbox snippet of code and the rest to get a basic mapbox preview

            <MapboxGL.MapView
            ref={map => { this._map = map }}
            animated={true}
        showUserLocation={true}
        userTrackingMode={MapboxGL.UserTrackingModes.Follow}
        styleURL={this.state.Street}
        style={Styles.Map.map}
        centerCoordinate={[this.props.region.longitude, this.props.region.latitude]}
        attributionEnabled={false}
        logoEnabled={false}     
        compassEnabled={true}
        onRegionWillChange={this.handleRegionChange}>
```

{

I get an error in the console

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Looking at the logs further I see

```
objc[20673]: Class MPExportableArtworkProperties is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaPlaybackCore.framework/MediaPlaybackCore (0x12a56aff0) and /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer (0x129264348). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[20673]: Class SMCalloutView is implemented in both /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F3A665E-E9A9-48C3-90ED-50C1E9C48DA3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/368D9223-62FC-4D50-B28C-E6EE1E3D6AB5/clustr.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox (0x110a1b068) and /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F3A665E-E9A9-48C3-90ED-50C1E9C48DA3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/368D9223-62FC-4D50-B28C-E6EE1E3D6AB5/clustr.app/clustr (0x10e852e10). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[20673]: Class SMCalloutMaskedBackgroundView is implemented in both /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F3A665E-E9A9-48C3-90ED-50C1E9C48DA3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/368D9223-62FC-4D50-B28C-E6EE1E3D6AB5/clustr.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox (0x110a1b090) and /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F3A665E-E9A9-48C3-90ED-50C1E9C48DA3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/368D9223-62FC-4D50-B28C-E6EE1E3D6AB5/clustr.app/clustr (0x10e852e38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[20673]: Class SMCalloutBackgroundView is implemented in both /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F3A665E-E9A9-48C3-90ED-50C1E9C48DA3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/368D9223-62FC-4D50-B28C-E6EE1E3D6AB5/clustr.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox (0x110a1b0e0) and /Users/michaelstokes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F3A665E-E9A9-48C3-90ED-50C1E9C48DA3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/368D9223-62FC-4D50-B28C-E6EE1E3D6AB5/clustr.app/clustr (0x10e852e88). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here goes ...

I hadn't read the docs clearly for `MapView` attribute usage so I was defining `attributionEnabled={false}` but I hadn't followed these simple instructions, and so that was the whole reason why I was getting `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

`Enable/Disable attribution on map. For iOS you need to add MGLMapboxMetricsEnabledSettingShownInApp=YES
to your Info.plist`

Over at https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/MapView.md