# What is causing compile error with React Native Firebase?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase

For the past couple of days, after installing ReactNative firebase in my application, I have been unable to build my React-Native (`react-native-cli: 2.0.1, react-native: 0.64.2`) app in iOS.
When I run react-native run-ios I get the following build fail:

```
CompileC /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/duworeact-
amefzhhuzrbghdbrflkfhviiskrq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/RNFirebase.build/Objects-
normal/x86_64/RNFirebaseFirestore.o
/Users/xxxx/Documents/projects/duworeact/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/
firestore/RNFirebaseFirestore.m normal x86_64 objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Based on several S/O posts, I've performed the following actions:

- Add Flipper to my podfile using the following code from the current official documentation:
    `use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.58.0'}) # should match the version of your Flipper client app`
- Deleted the **build** folder from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- Run `watchman watch-del-all && npm cache --force`
- Deleted the `node_modules` folder  and reinstalled modules using `npm i`
- Fixed an error with the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` based on [this S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445784/target-overrides-the-framework-search-paths-build-settings) by using `$(inherited)`
- From Flipper's documentation: *Install the dependencies by running `cd ios && pod install`*
- Finally, I checked to see if there were any processes running using grep. There were many from Xcode. I killed all processes and reset my MacBook just in case.

However, I am still unable to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31441#issuecomment-827585200)?

Comment: @Rohit I checked the file, the diffs are already there. Thanks