# EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT -- Error after pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, cocoapods

I have a currently working cocoapods, however whenever I want to add frameworks and run `pod install` I get this warning in the terminal and the project does not compile.

[image]

[image]

I have followed what it is suggesting, I already had the inherited flag in my build settings, and I tried deleting the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` from target build settings.

I have to run a `git reset --hard` to go back to my working cocoapods after removing the framework I wanted to add.

Edit: Added my podfile

[image]

Comment: do you have use_frameworks!  in your pod file?

Comment: @Johnykutty yes! U will also update my post with my pod file

Comment: i think that you can find an answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439856/xcode-6-cocoapods-error-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439856/xcode-6-cocoapods-error-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting)

Comment: already tried this, but unfortunately parts of the answer doesn't apply to this version of cocoapods and my project is completely in swift

Comment: desperate for help here folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of pain and suffering, I found the solution.

**We cannot have frameworks in cocoapods use other frameworks in your podfile.** I was using Atlas but added custom implementation that included `MBProgressHUD` which was the issue. I cannot import `MBProgressHUD` into `Atlas` because thats what was causing the issues above.

Not sure why but that was all there was to it.