# Resolving CocoaPods target overrides warnings for compilers

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using CocoaPods and am getting the warnings below. The error says to change the default settings to $(inherited), but that's not possible with these targets. You can only select from a list of options. Everything seems to be working, so I'm happy to just ignore the warnings, but if anyone can shed some light, I'd appreciate it!

```
[!] The `VitogoTests [Debug]` target overrides the `CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-VitogoTests/Pods-VitogoTests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `VitogoTests [Debug]` target overrides the `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-VitogoTests/Pods-VitogoTests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `VitogoTests [Release]` target overrides the `CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-VitogoTests/Pods-VitogoTests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `VitogoTests [Release]` target overrides the `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-VitogoTests/Pods-VitogoTests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30780124/1576402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but from my research, the warnings are from a bug in cocoapods, so it's safe to ignore them.

Comment: From the research I have done you are supposed to add the $(inherited) flag to any setting that you want to override from cocoapods, but since CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD and CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY don't accept free form values, I can't add the $(inherited) flag to the build setting.

Comment: I am going to have manually edit the targets created by cocoapods