# Cocoa Pods failed to link libraries while running in the debug mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I m using `pods` to link libraries like `AfNetworking`, `facebook` etc. and its working great in `release` mode but I want to check Variables value by debugging but it shows all the variables nil in release mode. I tried to run in `debug` mode by editing schema but it failed to compile showing various libraries not found error.

**Edit** I have tried updating the architectures.....but this isn't helping out.
**Error log in debug mode**

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/madept/Desktop/personally/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/madept/Desktop/personally/libCloudinary.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/madept/Desktop/personally/libCloudinary.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRAPIClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRAPIClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRAPIClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BITHockeyManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLCloudinary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRMediaManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLTransformation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRMediaManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDFileLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Zooplr.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Chat.o
      objc-class-ref in ZRManagedObject.o
      objc-class-ref in ZRTelescopingScrollView.o
      objc-class-ref in ZRAddMessageBarController.o
      objc-class-ref in ZRCreateAccountViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ZRAddressBookHelper.o
      objc-class-ref in Zooplr.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDTTYLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Zooplr.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ELCAlbumPickerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRMediaCaptureController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ELCImagePickerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRMediaCaptureController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EZAudioPlotGL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRMediaCaptureController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EZMicrophone", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRMediaCaptureController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EZRecorder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRMediaCaptureController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBErrorUtility", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRSocialClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRSocialClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequestConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRSocialClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in ZRSocialClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Mixpanel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRAnalyticsTracker.o
      objc-class-ref in Zooplr.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Zooplr.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSKeychain", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRAuthManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SVProgressHUD", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRAccountEditViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ZRAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SocketIO", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRChatSocketClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTTAttributedLabel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRBubbleViewTextMessage.o
  "_kReachabilityChangedNotification", referenced from:
      -[ZRAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in ZRAppDelegate.o
      -[ZRChatSocketClient init] in ZRChatSocketClient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Validate your User header search path and etc.

Comment: Is it different for debug and release mode...if different, then how do we set it?

Comment: seems you need to add architecture for all targets

Answer (score 8):

if the above answer didn't work for you, maybe the problem comes from when you installed the pods. Check if you had such message when running `pod install`

> The ProjectName [Release] target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

or a similar message but with `debug` instead of release  (or both).
If so, delete the pod project in your workspace in Xcode, then follow the answer to this question [The target ... overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods), I past it here :

> This definitely works most of the time:
>
> Go to your target Build Settings -> Other linker flags -> double click . Add $(inherited) to a new line.

And then run `pod install` again. It did it for me.

Comment: FWIW, I'm having this same issue and did not get any warnings when running pod install.

Comment: didn't have to delete the pod project in my workspace. I added $(inherited)  in Other linker flags and cleaned pod target (from product>scheme, change scheme and clean) re-started xcode and it worked. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

This means static libraries that you're using do not support x86_64 architecture,
So

1. Open "Build Settings" for "Pods" target, and add "x86_64" architecture (in "Architectures" and "Valid Architectures" section).
2. Set "Build Active Architectures Only" to "NO".
3. Clean "Pods" target.
4. Build your target.

Comment: I tried with your solution, it helped a bit as now ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/madept/Desktop/personally/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/madept/Desktop/personally/libCloudinary.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/madept/Desktop/personally/libCloudinary.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLCloudinary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRMediaManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLTransformation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ZRMediaManager.o

Comment: with 'Pods' do you mean 'Cocoapods' ?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the .a files in /Users/YourName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YourProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos. Then clean and build.This help me.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me after nothing else did.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is adding $(inherited) to:

- OTHER_LDFLAGS
- OTHER_CFLAGS
- FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS
- GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS

Tip: Inside Build Settings -> (search bar) -> type options above and add $(inherited)

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted the .a file, it won't worked for me, but when I Deleted the Project Folder in /Users/YourName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YourProject.
This help me.