# Problems with Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am having very bad problems with `CocoaPod`. I had to update `Cocoa pods` for Yosemite. I then ran pod update and got the following warning message:

```
[!] The `app [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

And

```
[!] The `app [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

EDIT:

I followed @mef link but did not know where to place the code?

Comment: _step 1.:_ eliminating cocoapods; _step 2.:_ using GIT (or other reliable solution); _step 3.:_ you don't need to thank me at all, just enjoy.

Comment: @holex how to remove cocoapods?

Comment: I don't know how you have added it to your project, honestly...

Comment: @holex if I could downvote a comment, I would. You do realize cocoapods is basically a wrapper around git, don't you? Except that it also resolves transitive dependencies and so much more...

Comment: @Mef, the cocoapod is a highly anti-pattern developer tool. we are here helping on poor OP in long term, and eliminate cocoapod is the only good solution in long term. no, further debate necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The target ... overrides the \`OTHER\_LDFLAGS\` build setting defined in \`Pods/Pods.xcconfig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods)

Comment: @Mef Tried that example, unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: @DevC Back up your project before doing this, but https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate can remove cocoapods entirely from your project.

Comment: @jlw that looks to be a very handy tool. Will it remove everything to do with Cocoapods? scripts and dependencies to Cocoapods. Might be easier to remove Cocoapods entirely and just add the source code from third party libraries. Cocoa Pods is giving me a headache at this stage.

Comment: @holex good luck with that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on Mefs link I was able to get it working. If anyone is wondering where to put `$(inherited)`, put it in the `Other linker Flags` section of your project.

[image]

Comment: You should tell where we can find that.