# Unable to build my XCode project in 64-bit mode (arm64)

Tags: xcode, sdwebimage, arm64

Since few month, XCode warn us to compile our iOS projects in 64-bit mode. I've added this arrchitecture, as mentionned. The problem is that I have some librairies, like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and [FSImageViewer](https://github.com/x2on/FSImageViewer) in my project, which create errors when I build the project. I've added this two librairies with cocoapods, as explained, and I have the latest version of the both librairies. I've also added all Frameworks (MapKit, ImageIO) in my project as mentionned.

Here are the build errors:
[image: Build errors]

My project configuration (the same as in the Pods project):
[image: Project build settings]

Do you have an idea how to avoid these annoying errors?

Many thanks!

Comment: Libraries which you have added are not built for arm64. Those libraries are just built for armv7 and armv7s. If you project file of those libraries, please build with arm64 as well. If not, then please find/request for arm64 version. The code has compiled successfully but during linking it is failing. Unable to find 64bit symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that I have some librairies, like SDWebImage and FSImageViewer in my project, which create errors when I build the project

You have already answered your own question. These libraries need to be built for both 32-bit and 64-bit. You cannot include a 32-bit library in a 64-bit app or vice versa; the library needs to contain slices for all the architectures you are building for.

Comment: Also, you are not using different Architectures settings for different build configurations, are you? That's a big mistake; you need to fix that.

Comment: Also, you should not have armv7s in that list. Use the Standard Architectures built-in setting - it consists of armv7 and arm64 only.

Comment: After many tries, I have reinstalled my pods librairies, and I noticed that there are some warnings as explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18376416/1881895. After I fixed it and now my project builds like a charm!