# ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've run `pod update` and, having had these errors:

```
target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

([The target ... overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods) )

I added `$(inherited)` to my Target.

However, I now get this:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions?