# Error "library not found for -lPods-MyProjectTests-KIF" when installing KIF in existing workspace

Tags: xcode6, integration-testing, cocoapods, ld, kif

I run into this error when adding KIF to an existing Xcode 6 workspace:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-MyProjectTests-KIF
```

What may be special about my situation that `MyProject.xcworkspace/` resides in the parent directory of `MyProject.xcproject/` (and depends on several other sibling projects as well):

```
./MyProject.xcworkspace/
./MyProject/
./MyProject/MyProject.xcworkspace/
./MyProject/Podfile
```

My `Podfile` is as follows:

```
target 'MyProjectTests', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'KIF', '~> 3.0', :configurations => ['Debug']
  workspace 'MyProject'
end
```

When I run `pod --project-directory=./MyProject install` and open `MyProject.xcworkspace` the target `MyProject` still compiles but I get the cited link error when building `MyProjectTests`.

How can I overcome that problem?

**UPDATE** My guess by now is that some settings are not [inherited](http://www.jontolof.com/cocoa/using-xcconfig-files-for-you-xcode-project/) correctly from `Pods-MyProjectTests.*.xcconfig` perhaps due to previous edits that removed `$(inherited)`s at the project or target level in some places (although this should normally produce [warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial guess (in the updated question) was wrong. `pod ... install` created a new `MyProject.xcworkspace\` as sibling to `Podfile`, not modify the one in the current directory. I had assumed the second by mistake.

These steps worked:

1. move `MyProject.xcworkspace/` down from its original location
2. run `pod install` in the new location
3. move `MyProject.xcworkspace/` back
   to its original location
4. in Xcode, delete its reference to `Pods.xcodeproj/`
   (because the relative locations in the file system have changed) and
   recreate new reference to it.

Since this is a bit cumbersome I have also posted a new question.