# Can I tell pod install that Xcode project and workspace reside in different directories?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

So I can tell [CocoaPod](http://cocoapods.org/)'s `pod install` the location of a project directory (with `--project-directory`). It will the apparently look for `Podfile`, `*xcproject/` and create or update `*.xcworkspace/` there.

Is there also an option for telling it that an existing workspace resides in a different directory from this project or the current directory?

The reason I am asking is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497959/error-library-not-found-for-lpods-myprojecttests-kif-when-installing-kif-in-e) related question.

Comment: What about this? 
http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#workspace

Comment: @orkenstein I made further changes in another iteration and tried your recipe. It indeed works (in my case with `workspace '../MyProject'`). I would not have guesses it from the documentation. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I shall accept it. Thx.

Comment: Yep, what I had in mind. I'll post it, could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaPods docs states:

> **workspace**
>    Specifies the Xcode workspace that should contain all the
>   projects.
>
> If no explicit Xcode workspace is specified and only one project exists in the same directory as the Podfile, then the name of that project is used as the workspace’s name.
>
> Example:
>   `workspace '../MyProject'`
>   `workspace 'folder/AnotherProject'`