# warning when using react native with cocoa pod

Tags: react-native

When using cocoa pod in a react native project I get the following warning when running `pod install`. Does anyone know why?

[!] The `[Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26077106/4043286

Note you need to double click on the on the debug and release targets and add $(inherited) to both, as can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrC7h.png