# Use of undeclared type PNObjectEventListener

Tags: swift, pubnub

[http://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-ios-apps-getting-started-with-swift-and-pubnub/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods)

I followed the above steps and added pods in my project. 
Initially, it has thrown some error, which I solved using

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods)

Now, when I run pod install, there are no errors and warnings.

The problem now being, when I tried to add **PNObjectEventListener** in *AppDelegate.swift* it says 'Use of undeclared type'.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hey after downloading the Pods are you working in the Workspace part of your project?

Comment: Yes, I clicked on the newly formed workspace file to launch my app after installing pods. Is this what you meant ?

Comment: Ok good. You should not need to use `import PubNub` in your project. It seems your errors are coming from the way you have installed your pods. Can you explain what error you got while installing the pods?

Comment: I got the error that I have mentioned in the link above in the question. I did as said in the answer and got rid of it. Apart from that, I didn't get any errors.

Comment: Can you share your Podfile so I can try and recreate your project?

Comment: platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'name' do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
pod 'PubNub', '~>4.0'

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the below import in the AppDelegate.Swift. Although , it is not necessary to add import, when it is already done in bridging header, after adding this line only, it worked for me!

```
import PubNub
```

Also, add exclamation marks if error pops up :

```
var client : PubNub
var config : PNConfiguration
```

Comment: var client : PubNub!
var config : PNConfiguration!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Incase anyone else is having this issue. If you created the XCode project and named it PubNub.... this causes the issue, as it cannot import the PubNub modules properly. I just dealt with this for about an hour then re-created the xcode project with name PMessage (Or any other name of your choosing just not PubNub) and the errors went away. Hope it helps.