# QuickBlox: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, architecture, sdk, quickblox

I am using Xcode 6.4 and installed QuickBlox framework using cocoapods. After using the framework I am getting some errors like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
```

[image]

Would anyone please help me to figure out. I am not able to fix this. Any suggestion will be appreciable.

> Update:

Below is my pod file

```
pod 'QuickBlox'
target 'myApp' do
```

Comment: Have you followed instructions from official site? Show your Pod file.

Comment: Can you post whole build log (through pastebin). Are you opening workspace instead of project? Is the library included in "build with libraries",

Answer (score 1):

Go to your target Build Settings -> Other linker flags -> double click . Add $(inherited) to a new line. This will fix the issue. 
You can find more detail by using below link
[The target ... overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods)

Answer (score 1):

So I have been trying for days to figure out why quickblox package is not letting me build the app in ios. After a lot of clean project, pod installs etc. I came out to a conclusion. Whenever I create an app with swift language selected in android studio I have the same error with you but whenever I select objective-C as IOS language the app is running properly. In my opinion, It is prop an error-bug of the package which needs to be fixed by quickblox developers.

Answer (score 1):

After getting in touch with QuickBlox developers I was provided with the following information :

At this moment for correctly launch samples in iOS simulator you need update pod file with next snippet:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

And reinstall the pods.

Podfile example (update pod file for the chat sample swift):

```rb
platform :ios, "13.0"

use_frameworks!

inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'sample-chat-swift' do
    pod 'QuickBlox', '~> 2.17.10'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.4.7'
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 2.0.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```

They promised to release a new SDK within a month.