# Quickblox Flutter Ios Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: ios, flutter, undefined, quickblox, arm64

I am making a new flutter project adding quickblox in pubspec.yaml making pubg get pod install and then I am trying to run it in ios device. I always get this error. Am I missing something on ios that I need to add it in xcode? I havent worked with xcode a lot so my knowledge is limited.Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

looks like the issue is caused by [QuickBlox: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485722/quickblox-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64/71048238#71048238)

I assume that when iOS devs release a new iOS SDK they will also update the one for Flutter.