# xcode 7 pods: library not found for -lAFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I've been trying to use pods to integrate [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native-mobile/ios-objc/no-api) to [Telegram app](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram) for quite some time now (both are Objective-C projects).

First off, we copied over the podfile from Auth0 to Telegram:

Auth0's podfile:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"

inhibit_all_warnings!

target "basic-sample" do
    pod "Lock", "~> 1.24"
    pod "Lock-Facebook", "~> 2.0"
    pod "JWTDecode", "~> 0.2.0"
    pod "SimpleKeychain", "~> 0.3"
    pod "MBProgressHUD", "~> 0.9"
end
```

Copied over to Telegram's podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
# use_frameworks!

target 'Telegraph' do
    pod "Lock", "~> 1.24"
    pod "Lock-Facebook", "~> 2.0"
    pod "JWTDecode", "~> 0.2.0"
    pod "SimpleKeychain", "~> 0.3"
    pod "MBProgressHUD", "~> 0.9"
end

target 'Share' do

end

target 'watchkitapp' do

end

target 'watchkitapp Extension' do

end
```

Upon `pod install`, I get this crap-ton warnings:

```
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Share` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Share/Pods-Share.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Share/Pods-Share.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Share` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Share/Pods-Share.release.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Share/Pods-Share.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Telegraph` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Telegraph` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.release.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `watchkitapp` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp/Pods-watchkitapp.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp/Pods-watchkitapp.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `watchkitapp` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp/Pods-watchkitapp.release.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp/Pods-watchkitapp.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `watchkitapp Extension` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp Extension/Pods-watchkitapp Extension.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp Extension/Pods-watchkitapp Extension.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `watchkitapp Extension` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp Extension/Pods-watchkitapp Extension.release.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp Extension/Pods-watchkitapp Extension.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

[!] The `Telegraph [Debug]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Telegraph [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_CFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Telegraph [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Telegraph [Release]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Telegraph [Release]` target overrides the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Telegraph [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_CFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Telegraph [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Telegraph/Pods-Telegraph.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Share [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Share/Pods-Share.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Share [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Share/Pods-Share.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `watchkitapp Extension [Debug]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp Extension/Pods-watchkitapp Extension.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `watchkitapp Extension [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp Extension/Pods-watchkitapp Extension.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `watchkitapp Extension [Release]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp Extension/Pods-watchkitapp Extension.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `watchkitapp Extension [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-watchkitapp Extension/Pods-watchkitapp Extension.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

And I also get errors in Xcode that I could not solve (missing directories).

After trying to solve those, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods?lq=1), which told me to add `$(inherited)` to my Other Linker Flags. And I did it, like so:

[image]

Of note is that the 'Share' target also has an extra linker flag, `lc++`. I added `$(inherited)` to all of the targets.

I then get this error:

> ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking clang: error: linker command
>
> failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I added -l"AFNetworking", but that didn't change anything.

Is there anything else I can try? Yes, I'm using the .xcworkspace app.

Comment: Are these both Objective-C projects?

Comment: Yes. Ugh, sorry I forgot to add that. Question edited.

Comment: Did you find the solution?