# Error with pod firebase to Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I added Alamofire before I add firebase to my project and it was working just fine after that I pod `Firebase/Core` and install it and run my project with `.xcworkspace` but when I run the simulator I got a long error message end with this.

> ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture x86_64
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

how can i fix it
i use the last update of Xcode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292090/firebase-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but please check these things:
- Do you have an entry point?
- Do you use the same iOS version in XCode and in the pod? For instance, it would be a problem if your XCode want to build it for an iOS 11 device but in your pod file, you have set iOS 10.

Comment: thanks i fixed it by adding @UIApplicationMain to AppDelegate class