# Firebase FCM with google plus cordova plugin conflict - IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, google-plus

I am using

```
"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^2.4.0",
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.0.0",
```

I have added IOS platform

```
"cordova-ios": "^5.0.1",
```

and when I try to build it in XCode it fails with below error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMLogger", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleIPhoneUtilities(GIPReachability.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note: I have tried everything mentioned in this question.
[Firebase Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292090/firebase-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

**Build works if I remove any one of the plugins.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone wondering, I solved it by downgrading to

```
`"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.1",`
```

Latest version `8.0.0` is using `Pods` to manage dependencies which will be global/project-wide, while 7.0.1 handles dependencies locally i.e only for that plugin. So it won't affect any other plugin(s) using those same dependencies.

Comment: Hello, I am getting same error while building in IOS. But when I try to downgrade to version 7.0.1 google login is not working in Android. So this downgrading I have to do only in IOS?

Comment: this version is working on IOS but not working in android also if we use this our app rejected because this is using UIWebView.

Comment: if i use this version then i am getting UIWebView issue upload time

Answer (score 0):

With this version it has worked perfectly.

```
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.1"
```

It should also be taken into account that sometimes it is necessary to add **REVERSED_CLIENT_ID**

Xcode -> info -> URL Types (add this)

[image]