# Firebase Unity - Undefined Symbol errors for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

Firebase
6.15.2

Unity
2019.4

Xcode
11.6

OSX Catalina
10.15.6

Hi there,

Relative newbie, so apologies if I’m missing anything obvious here…

I’m attempting to build a unity project for iPhone using Firebase, using cocoapods.
I'm only using Firestore within the project.
I keep getting the following set of errors  when building to a device,

```
Undefined symbol: firebase::auth::User::GetToken(bool)
Undefined symbol: firebase::auth::AuthStateListener::~AuthStateListener()
Undefined symbol: firebase::auth::Auth::AddAuthStateListener(firebase::auth::AuthStateListener*)
Undefined symbol: firebase::auth::Auth::current_user()
Undefined symbol: firebase::g_auth_initializer
Undefined symbol: typeinfo for firebase::auth::AuthStateListener
Undefined symbol: firebase::auth::Auth::GetAuth(firebase::App*, firebase::InitResult*)
```

I’ve tried all of the suggestions in this thread :
[iOS - Firebase Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292090/firebase-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64?newreg=870a8f1518514c5ea50fc7dd9236b723)

And am at a loss as to what to try next, besides smashing my head into the desk one more time.

Any pointers would be hugely appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

A good thing to remember with the Unity SDK is that it's different enough from the iOS SDK that the specific fixes there might mess with the games tooling a little bit.

When you export, [EDM4U](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) should auto-generate a `Podfile` and run install for you. So make sure you just go straight to the `xcworkspace` rather than opening the `xcproj`. If you're successfully running `pod install` for example on the generated project, then CocoaPods should already be setup enough for this to not be the issue.

Now the linker errors you're getting are part of the C++ SDK. This is the middle layer of the SDK:

```
|                Unity (C#)                                 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|                   C++                                     |
|-------------------------------------------                |
| Android (Java/Kotlin) | iOS (ObjC/Swift) |  Desktop (C++) |
```

These files you're looking for on iOS are `.a` files in `Assets/Plugins/iOS`. If you're not using the Unity Package Manager, make sure you haven't removed these (`.a` is a common exclusion pattern for version control) - and try re-adding the SDK if you have. For the Unity Package Manager, it should just work - you can try deleting the `Library` directory with Unity closed and let Unity regenerate this (pulling down the packages in the process). I believe that the file you're missing is `libFirebaseCppAuth.a`, although whatever is causing an issue here could be affect the other `.a` files that are needed.

If the file is included, ensure that it's included in your iOS build:

[image: screenshot of the "Select platforms for plugins" panel for libFirebaseCppAuth.a with iOS selected]

LMK if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding the Firebase Authentication package on my Unity Project.

I don't use any authentication on my game, so it is a workaround that solved my problem. I think there's a bug on Firebase core requiring these authentication package.